# printf boost:tuple

Tags: c++, boost

Is there're way to pass boost::tuple to printf()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, because `printf` requires certain format specifiers. You'd need to print each element out at a time.

You might make a template function that iterates over the elements of the tuple, printing them out. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple) address that. That said, that again won't work unless each element can be printed out with `printf`.

Rather, why not use `iostream` instead? Then you can just say `std::cout << theTuple`.

Answer (score 1):

No, because "printf" is a C function and has no idea how to handle C++ objects. That said, if all you want to do is create a formatted message, you might want to check out [The Boost Format Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/doc/format.html).

Comment: std::string hovewer has c_str()

Comment: @idimba,... and? The result of c_str() is const char*. You cannot pass an object of type std::string directly to printf.