# C++0x tuples have no iterators, right?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++11, tuples

Looking into the standard N3291 I do not find any reference for `tuple` to support `begin()` and `end()`. But when I look at my notes from years back I seem to have jotted down that I need to look into that later. And here we are.

I can not find any trace of `tuple<...>.begin()` or `tuple<...>.end()` in the current C++0x standard, is this correct? It is not possible to pass a tuple with its iterators to an algorithm, nor can one `for`-loop over it, right?

```
tuple<int,string,double> val;
for(auto a : val) cerr << val;     // very wrong!
```

which is of course nonsense, because what should `auto` be?

I need the confirmation that my notes contain an error, and that there is no way to get those iterators for tuple elements. Or maybe there was an abandoned path in the standards discussion?

Note: I am aware of that one can use *TMP* or *Variadic Templates* to implement a *do-for-all-elements-of-a-tuple*, but my question is really about iterators.

Comment: Why not for-loop with index from 0 to `::tuple_size` and access elements via `std::get<i>` ?

Comment: @osgx: The template parameter has to be a compile-time constant!

Comment: Check this question and its answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/1198260/196561

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/index.html) has iterable tuples -- `boost::fusion::vector<>` -- along with many [iteration, query, and transformation algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm.html) for tuples.

It also has code to [adapt `boost::tuple<>` for use with those iterators and algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/boost__tuple.html); you could take that code and modify it to work with `std::tuple<>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Iterators for tuples would be as useful as iterators for class members. Tuples just aren't meant to have that kind of--iterable--content.

Comment: That is a good comparison. Although, I am sure, many reflection fans (read: Java fans) find iterators for class members quite useful... ;-)

Comment: @towi, oops :) It does have its uses there.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no iterators for tuples. Iterators are a run-time concept, while tuples are a compile-time construct. As you rightly remarked, there isn't even a way to make sense of a generic tuple iterator.

If you need a type-erasing runtime container, you could use a vector of `boost::any`s.

Comment: Nono, I just wanted to make sense of my notes.