# Does boost support serialization of c++11's std::tuple?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, c++11, boost-serialization

Does boost support serialization of c++11's std::tuple?

I couldn't find a tuple.hpp header file at /boost/serialization/

I'm using boost 1.52.0 (happy to upgrade if need be, but it seems like the [changes in version 1.53](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_53_0.html) doesn't have anything related to this).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of the box, no. You'll have to write the serializer yourself. Luckily, someone already did:

[C++0x tuple boost serialization](https://sydius.me/2011/02/c0x-tuple-boost-serialization/) (also in [github](https://github.com/Sydius/serialize-tuple))

Comment: Is there a solution available that doesn't use variadic templates?

Comment: more than 5 years has passed, is there any official solution?

Answer (score 3):

and here is another implementation:

https://github.com/galaxyeye/atlas/blob/master/atlas/serialization/tuple.h

with the test code :

https://github.com/galaxyeye/atlas/blob/master/libs/serialization/test/tuple.cpp

enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [C++17's fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), you can easily implement a serializer:

```cpp
template <typename Archive, typename... Types>
void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive &ar, std::tuple<Types...> &t, const unsigned int)
{
    std::apply([&](auto &...element)
                { ((ar & element), ...); },
                t);
}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54053084/4184203).