# how could I serialize boost tuple?

Tags: boost, boost-serialization, boost-mpi

when trying to broad cast an element with boost_tuple using boost mpi:

```
broadcast(world,J,0);
```

I have the error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: 'class boost::tuples::tuple<int, int, int, int, int>' has no member named 'serialize'
         t.serialize(ar, file_version);
```

What could I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the analogous to [Does boost support serialization of c++11's std::tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744303/does-boost-support-serialization-of-c11s-stdtuple/14928368#14928368)

Alternatively, use c++14 `std::index_sequence` with c++17's [generalized fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? I tried doing the analogous of what is done for `std::tuple` but I do not find it easy, I am getting compilation errors.