# std::tuple and memcpy

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I am aware that the standard declares that `std::tuple` is not trivially copiable so `std::memcpy` will have an undefined behavior on this type, but are there infos (maybe something compiler specific) to safely memcpy `std::tuple` with basic types (`int`, `float`)?

A possible example:

```cpp
auto my_computation = [](...){ something...; return std::make_tuple(...) }

auto ret = my_computation(...);

unsigned char buf[...];
memcpy(buf, &ret, sizoof(ret));

//send the bytes out to another device
```

I have had no issues (for now) with this raw memcpy but I am not sure if it is reliable (g++ (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424) 10.3.1 20210424).

I can assure that the receiver architecture is compatible with this bytes representation (e.g. endianess) so this is not a problem.

Comment: Could you explain why you would need this? (e.g.: specific use-case)

Comment: I have to transfer tuple content into a byte array (char*) for network transfer

Comment: What about trying with some tuples and taking the addresses of all elements to check if they are contiguous ? (Note that this could be compiler-dependent.)

Comment: you can memcpy an `int` and a `float` seperately. On the other end you can then memcpy the `int` and the `float` into `int` and `float` members of a tuple

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14744303/580083

Comment: Is it just any old tuple (of primitive types), or do you have something specific in mind?  See also: https://wandbox.org/permlink/cQ2NEkQBAa4A3Paz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't std::tuple<int> be trivially copyable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779985/why-cant-stdtupleint-be-trivially-copyable)

Comment: Serialize it yourself by accessing the `int` and the `float` individually. IMO that's the only portable proper way to do it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I agree.  I bet `memcpy` works though (for what the OP seems to have in mind).

Comment: @PaulSanders note that "works" and "appears to work" are different things.

Comment: In the old days, there were these things named `struct`s...

Comment: Specifically, concerning network communication, I would've concerns to simply copy bytes. If sender and receiver have different endianess, then the better solution for integrals is bit-arithmetic to isolate the bytes. Actually, floating points have endianess as well. The only solution, I'm aware of is to memcpy the bytes of the floating point into a byte buffer and then reverse it before sending if necessary.

Comment: gcc knows what `memcpy()` does and happily eliminates it. So I thought it would be smart enough to merge multiple calls to `memcpy()` too: https://godbolt.org/z/ceGvThEc7 Alas that is not the case. Using `memcpy()` on each member of a tuple nicely optimizes into a load and store but they aren't merged.

Comment: One thing that surprised me a bit was that `std::tuple<int, float>` has the float first followed by the int. Is that mandated by the standard or unspecified?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow This is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow yes it is unspecified. Take e.g. a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597006/stdtuple-memory-alignment).

Comment: One more reason to define your own structure over using tuple then.

Comment: In addition to memcpy'ing the int and float to your buffer, you'll also need to host-to-network swizzle the bytes.  (And presumably both sides are using IEEE 754 float format, which is not required/guaranteed by the C++ standard — it's an implementation detail.)

Comment: OK OP, [mre] please.  Let's see what you're really trying to do.

Comment: `std::tuple` in this context fits to this quote: "Every new powerful feature will be overused and misused" - [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://www.stroustrup.com/quotes.html). `std::tuple` should be used in template code, when context and types of fields is unknown in all other cases `struct` is more readable and maintainable, since fields have names which are form of documentation.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow a recursive implementation of tuple does that. Probably MSVC platform.

Comment: @Red.Wave gcc on godbolt

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow recursive tuple?

Comment: @Red.Wave You would have to check the libstdc++ source yourself.

Comment: I may add another example. We use a multicore-environment (all same core-arch) where on each core components can be placed which are connected via some templated interfaces comparable to the etl::delegate [link](https://www.etlcpp.com/delegate.html). So for the user the look and feel is like a function call while underneath a packet-ipc sends the actual data. And those templates use parameter packs. Internally they are then packed into tuples and are sent to the other core. I think since all cores use the exact same compiler and options and code-base this will work.

Answer (score 3):

Tuple memory representation is implementation defined, just like the order of derived class object and base class object.
If your data blocks are large and individual copy creates performance  issues (which is a rare and niche problem), you should create own structures with standard memory layout. This also would allow implementation of byte order change.

Comment: A bit of a technicality: these things are implementation specific, but not implementation defined. In the C++ Standard, "implementation defined" means that a conforming implementation must document its behavior.

Comment: @PeteBecker so due to the fact that this is "specific" and not "defined" there are no documentation available about the memory representation of std::tuple?

Comment: @kmc -- there may or may not be documentation. "Implementation defined" is about what the C++ Standard requires; it means that documentation is **required**.