# How to iterate over a TR1 tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, c++03, stdtuple

Being stuck in TR1 land, for a test program I need to perform certain operations on a number of objects of specific types. I have a couple of tuple type definitions which look like this:

```
typedef std::tr1::tuple< bool
                       , signed char
                       , signed short
                       , signed int
                       , signed long long
                       , unsigned char
                       , unsigned short
                       , unsigned int
                       , unsigned long long >  integral_types;
```

From each tuple type an object is to be created. I then have function templates similar to this:

```
template<typename T>
void invoke_operation_1(T& obj);
```

These need to be called for all objects in a tuple object.

How do I do that in C++03?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Isn't there `tuple_size` and `get` in tr1?

Comment: The [Boost.Fusion approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1201902/560648) should be C++03-compatible. A [manual approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1198432/560648) is here.

Comment: @sbi: Who said anything about homework? SO questions are expected to demonstrate prior research. :) Your urgency is not relevant...

Comment: @jrok: I know there's `get()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iterate over tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple)

Comment: Oops, I noticed that your question specifically asks about C++03: nevermind the close vote. The two questions could (should?) probably be merged in a single one, though.

Comment: @LucTouraille yes, the C++03/C++11 question duplicity is seen often these days. Just flagged it for the mods to merge the two questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [boost::fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html) if you need to call the same templated function for every object in the tuple. E.g.

```
template<typename T>
void invoke_operation_1(T& obj)
{
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
}

struct executor
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const
    {
        invoke_operation_1(t);
    }
};

typedef boost::tuple< bool
                       , signed char
                       , signed short
                       , signed int
                       , signed long long
                       , unsigned char
                       , unsigned short
                       , unsigned int
                       , unsigned long long >  integral_types;
int main()
{
    integral_types t(true, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    boost::fusion::for_each(t, executor());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was hesitant to bring in boost::fusion just to do that, but this looks really convenient, so I might give it a try anyway. What conditions must `executor` meet? Would some `std::tr1::bind()` expression work instead? With argument placeholders?

Comment: @sbi The docuentation says a `Regular Callable Object` so a bind expression should ok.

Comment: @sbi since `invoke_operation_1` is a template and not a function, I doubt `boost::bind` will work. At least I could not find any overloads taking template template arguments, which would be needed here.

Comment: @ArneMertz: You got a point there, I just ran into this. `:)` Well, then I'll just have to wrap it into a function object, I think. Thanks, @mkaes!

Comment: Well, since in the end I did indeed use fusion, I accepted this answer. Thanks to everyone who put effort into this!

Answer (score 8):

There was a feature just finalized in Bristol for C++14 to address this very problem. It's not too hard to deal with.

For the simpler case, you can use a recursive template. It's a smidge of a mess though without partial function specialization and such.

```
template<typename Tup, std::size_t N> struct visit_detail {
     template<typename F> static void call(Tup& t, F f) {
         f(std::tr1::get<N>(t));
         return visit_detail<Tup, N+1>::call(t, f);
     }
};
template<typename Tup> struct visit_detail<Tup, std::tr1::tuple_size<Tup>::value> {
    template<typename F> static void call(Tup& t, F f) {}
}

template<typename Tup, typename F> void visit(Tup& t, F f) {
    return visit_detail<Tup, 0>::call(t, f);
}
```

Here f can be hardcoded or a parameter function object or whatever you want.

Comment: Ah, so there is indeed a `tuple_size`. Thanks, I think I can work it out from there!

Comment: @DeadMG: Yikes! Can you remember the name of the C++14 feature, for reference?

Comment: [N3493](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3493.html) slightly revised

Comment: @DeadMG: Thanks; looks interesting (hope they don't retain the text 'compile-time' in the final wording, though!)

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename tup, typename N>
struct visit_detailImpl {
    template<typename f>
    static void call(tup& t, f f) {
        f(std::tr1::get<N::value>(t));
        return visit_detailImpl<tup, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N::value + 1> >::call(t, f);
    }
};
template<typename tup> // end recursion struct
struct visit_detailImpl<tup, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, std::tr1::tuple_size<tup>::value> > {
    template<typename f>
    static void call(tup& t, f f) {}
};
template<typename tup, typename Fn>
void for_each_tup(tup& t, Fn f) {
    return visit_detailImpl<tup, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> >::call(t, f);
}
```

Comment: "Being stuck in TR1 land..."