# Apply functions belonging to other classes through variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Say I have three classes, `ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `ClassC`. And all three of these classes have a function called `updateValue(int)`. And then I have controller class called, `Controller`. Who's constructor is templated like the following:

```
class Controller
{
  public:
    template <class...Classes>
    Controller(Classes & ...classes); // maybe initialize a tuple?

    void setValues(int val)
    {
      // unpack whatever data structure and call each classes updateValue(int)
    }
  private:
    std::tuple<Classes...classes> packedClasses; // Not sure if this is good idea? This will not compile
};
```

As you can see, I want to be able to take the classes from some data structure, and call their functions. For example, in main I would have:

```
int main()
{
  ClassA A;
  ClassB B;
  ClassC C;

  Controller controller1(A,B);
  Controller controller2(A,C);
  Controller controller3(B,C);
  Controller controller4(A,B,C);

  controller4.setValues(20);

}
```

Each class has their own way of updating a value, for example `ClassA` has `setValue(int)`, `ClassB` has `setInt(int)`, and `ClassC` has `updateNumber(int)`. My plan is to write the function `updateValue` into each of these classes that will call their setter functions. However, I am not sure how to achieve what it is I am trying to do. How can I unpack all of the classes and call their function `updateValue(int)`?

Comment: Can you have template class (`template <class...Classes> class Controller;`)?

Comment: Else you need erasure type... (`std::function<void(int)>` does the job for your example).

Comment: `std::tuple<Classes...classes> packedClasses;` should be `std::tuple<Classes...> packedClasses;`.  Using that you can use the dupe target to call a function on each member of the tuple.

Comment: Is the idea that controller class manages the lifetime of the classes passed in, or do they live elsewhere and the controller just reference them?

Comment: I reopened as I didn't see the class wasn't a template.  If you can make it one then you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387354/template-tuple-calling-a-function-on-each-element

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I can do that. That will be fine.

Comment: @super just a reference to them. They will not manage the lifetime.

Comment: @NathanOliver, how would that apply with calling the classes functions though? Generally, when you call a function belonging to another class, you have to do something like `&A::func()` don't you?

Comment: You use a lambda that takes the object and calls the class member function on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your current interface, you might do something like:

```
class Controller
{
 public:
    template <class...Classes>
    Controller(Classes&... classes)
    {
        mF = [&](int val) { (classes.updateValue(val), ...); }; // Fold expression from C++17
    }

    void setValues(int val)
    {
        mF(val);
    }
    private:
        std::function<void(int)> mF;
    };
```

Comment: That is awesome. How would this work if you were trying to get their values and push them back into a vector?