# How to combine multiple variadic templated tuple classes into one class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I have changed my approach from [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854036/apply-functions-belonging-to-other-classes-through-variadic-templates) to templatize the entire class instead and place it inside a variadic tuple. I can now use getters and setters the way that I would like them to be created. However, now I am trying to take it a step forward and combine the individual controllers into one controller.

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_HPP
#define CONTROLLER_HPP

#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename...Classes>
class Controller
{
  public:
    Controller(Classes&...objects) : objects(objects...){}

    void setValues(int value)
    {
      std::apply([&](auto&...x) { (x.updateValue(value),...);}, objects);
    }

    void getValues(std::vector<int> &values)
    {
      std::apply([&](auto&...x) { (values.push_back(x.get()),...);}, objects);
    }
  private:
    std::tuple<Classes&...> objects;
};

#endif
```

With this I can do the following:

```
classA A;
classB B;
classC C;
classD D;
classE E;
classF F;
classG G;

Controller controller1(A,B,C);
Controller controller2(D,E);
Controller controller3(F,G);

controller1.setValues(20);
controller2.setValues(13);
controlelr3.setValues(32);
```

However, I want to take it a step further and combine the two like so:

```
Controller master(controller1,controller2,controller3);
master.setValues(40);
```

I have looked [at this post talking about joining variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662632/variadic-variadic-template-templates), however I think this returns a type(?) and not a class. I also tried creating two overloaded classes, however I don't think I am creating the overload correctly:

```
template<typename...Classes>
class Controller
{
  public:
    Controller(Classes&...objects) : objects(objects...){}

    void setValues(int value)
    {
      std::apply([&](auto&...x) { (x.updateValue(value),...);}, objects);
    }

    void getValues(std::vector<int> &values)
    {
      std::apply([&](auto&...x) { (values.push_back(x.get()),...);}, objects);
    }
  private:
    std::tuple<Classes&...> objects;
};

template<Controller<typename ... > class Controllers, typename ...Classes>
class Controller<Controllers<Classes&...classes>...>
{
  // create a new controller that takes all the combined classes
};
```

How can I combine any number of templated variadic templated classes into one class? I do have the ability to use C++17.

Comment: Make a functor with overloaded `operator()`, one that takes care or `Controller<...>`s and one that take care of anything else. Then you can pass that to `std::apply` instead of your current lambda.

Comment: @super would you like to give an example?

Comment: @super That would require the child-controllers have a lifetime that exceeds the master for no practical reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename...Classes>
class Controller
{
  Controller( std::tuple<Classes&...> tup ):objects(tup) {}
public:
  template<class...Rhs>
  Controller<Classes..., Rhs...> operator+( Controller<Rhs...> rhs ) const {
    return std::tuple_cat( objects, rhs.objects );
  }
```

...

giving us:

```
Controller master = controller1+controller2+controller3;
master.setValues(40);
```

Comment: I guess this is one way to do this, however it would require the user to use `+` instead of constructing it inside of the class.

Comment: @Sailanarmo Yes, if you feel exposing the algebraic nature of your operation to the consumer is a bad thing.

Comment: Nice approach, very little additional boilerplate.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont what is wrong with constructing them in parentheses? You said it would require the child-controllers to have a lifetime that exceeds the master?

Comment: @Sailanarmo No: super's implementation (which I could understand from his brief comment) had a problem.  I could list things wrong with your plan of passing them via construction; it doesn't reflect the algebraic nature of the operation (the operation distributes, for example), it requires a whole pile of extra boilerplate, and it convolves "control these instances" with "control the instances that these controllers control" (which is the reason why super's solution had the bug I pointed out).  This is the turing tar pit, everything is equivalent, but some things are shaped better.

Comment: @Sailanarmo The fact that your operation is concatination makes it algebraic, and expressing algebraic operations with algebra leads to simple, clear, elegant code.  And as your state is a tuple of references, the result is also pretty efficient and easy for a compiler to elide intermediate results.  A solution with the syntax you ask for would require at lot more ugly boilerplate.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont okay, now I understand this solution a lot better, thank you for clearing that up for me. I will select this as the answer.