# How to find maximum dereferenceable-level of the parameter T using template

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2013

I am designing a *"dereferencer"* class, for fun.

I wrote some `struct`s and `alias`s :

```
template <class _T>
using deref_type = decltype(*std::declval<_T>());

template <class _T, class _SFINAE>
struct is_derefable : std::false_type {};

template <class _T>
struct is_derefable< _T, deref_type<_T> > : std::true_type
{
    using return_type = deref_type<_T>;
};

template<class _T>
using check_derefable = is_derefable<T, deref_type<T>>;
```

and let's say that there is a variable with type `T = std::vector<int**>::iterator`, which is the iterator dereferenced into a level-2 pointer, thus has a 3-level dereferenceability.

Here, I want to know the maximum level of "dereferenceability" of an arbitrary type `T`, at the **compile-time**.

```
std::cout << deref_level<std::vector<int**>::iterator>::max << std::endl; // this should prints 3
```

I thought that it would be way similar to generating a sequence at the compile-time: [Template tuple - calling a function on each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387354/template-tuple-calling-a-function-on-each-element)
, but I can't draw a concrete picture of it.

Here are what I've tried:

```
template<class _TF, class _T>
struct derefability {};

template<int _N, class _derefability>
struct deref_level;

template<int _N, class _T>
struct deref_level<_N, derefability<std::false_type, _T>>
{
    static const int max = _N;
};

template<int _N, class _T>
struct deref_level<_N, derefability<std::true_type, _T>> : 
    deref_level<_N + 1, derefability<typename check_derefable<deref_type<_T>>::type, deref_type<_T>>>{};

deref_level<0, derefability<check_derefable<T>::type, T>::max;
```

but it does not work...(compiler says that **max** is not a member of tje class) What went wrong?

Comment: Just so you know, identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (`_T`, `_N`, `_SFINAE`, etc.) are reserved to the implementation for *any use*. It's a habit worth breaking.

Comment: "Does not work" is not specific enough. Was there a compilation error? Any other error? You might want to read this: [mcve].

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica Thanks for your advice, but I don't get what "reserved to the implementation for *any use*" means. Can you write some examples of that usage for me, please?

Comment: @Moon See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/509868).

Comment: The implementation is your compiler and system headers. The C++ standard says user programs can't use such identifiers, only the implementation. You aren't **allowed** to use them yourself, under pain of undefined behavior. I can't very well show you an example of something that shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of work, I was able to write code that works without causing an error in MSVC13.

First of all, I needed a robust module to check the ***dereferenceability*** of the type.

Since the struct-level SFINAE check fails, I took another method that deduces the return type from **overloaded functions** with `auto->decltype` expression, based on the answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154394/12515061)

```
template<class T>
struct is_dereferenceable
{
private:
    template<class _type>
    struct dereferenceable : std::true_type
    {
        using return_type = _type;
    };

    struct illegal_indirection : std::false_type
    {
        using return_type = void*;
    };

    template<class _type>
    static auto dereference(int)->dereferenceable<
        decltype(*std::declval<_type>())>;

    template<class>
    static auto dereference(bool)->illegal_indirection;

    using dereferenced_result = decltype(dereference<T>(0));

public:
    using return_type = typename dereferenced_result::return_type;
    static const bool value = dereferenced_result::value;
};
```

Now I have a robust dereferenceability-checker, the remaining part becomes far easy.

```
template< class T,
    class D = typename is_dereferenceable<T>::return_type >
struct dereferenceability;

template< class T >
struct dereferenceability<T, void*>
{
    using level = std::integral_constant<int, 0>;
};

template< class T, class D >
struct dereferenceability<T, D&>
{
    using level = std::integral_constant<int, dereferenceability<D>::level::value + 1>;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(dereferenceability<int>::level::value == 0, "something went wrong");
    static_assert(dereferenceability<int****>::iterator>::level::value == 4, "something went wrong");
    return 0;
}
```

I've tested codes above in Visual Studio 2013, and no error occured.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursive implementation using SFINAE directly:

```
template <class T, class = void>
struct deref_level {
    enum : std::size_t { value = 0 };
};

template <class T>
struct deref_level<T, decltype(void(*std::declval<T const &>()))> {
    enum : std::size_t { value = deref_level<decltype(*std::declval<T const &>())>::value + 1 };
};
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UA7KlTF3w7azkXEm)

Comment: I have another question, why should I use 'void'-casting wrapping 'decltype'? Is it a "safety net" for the case when deduction failed? If then, `void(error-type)` is cast into `void`?

Comment: Plus, is there any other possible solution that using `static const int` type for `max_level`, rather than `enum`?

Comment: Oh, I've only tested it for several types, but not built it. When I build the codes in VS2013, an error occurs : `error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.`

Comment: I found a way to solve it. Just use another struct for checking SFINAE and use it. I added the codes to the edited answer of @Quentin.

Comment: I apologize. The codes @Quentin wrote do not work on my VS2013. When the original Quentin code built, I get a message `error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler`. For the stuct-using SFINAE checked version, it was successfully compiled for nothing inside the `deref_level`  struct, but after I put `enum ` code in it then I get a message `error C2100: illegal indirection`.

Comment: @Moon the cast to `void` is just because the final type must be the same as the default type argument for the specialization to be picked up. I have avoided any variant of `static` member variables for `value`, as I do not remember the C+11 rules around their definition (particularly with ODR). I'm currently reviewing your edit, but IIUC it's not fully functional because VS2013 still freaks out when you actually put in `value`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what went wrong with your template example, but here's an implementation using a recursive consteval function:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, int N = 0>
consteval int deref_level()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer<T>::value) {
        typedef typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type U;
        return deref_level<U, N + 1>();
    } else {
        return N;
    }
}

int main() {
    return deref_level<int****>(); // Returns 4
}
```

Comment: Beware that this is C++20, but the question is tagged C++11. It is also restricted to pointers, but OP wants to handle any dereferenceable type such as iterators.

Comment: @Quentin Ah, I didn't see that