# Can I insert various typed elements into a container?

Tags: c++, types, stl, containers

I tried to raise stack overflow using template like the following :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define endl '\n'

template <class T>
// void next (T a) cout << a++ << endl;       // can't write in a line without {}
void next (T a)
{
    if (typeid(a) == typeid((char) 'a') || typeid(a) == typeid((unsigned char) 'a'))
    {
        cout << typeid(a).name() << " : " << (int) a << " + 1 = " << (int) ++a << " (converted to ASCII value)" << endl;    
    } else
    {
        cout << typeid(a).name() << " : " << a << " + 1 = " << ++a << endl;
    }
    // there will be more alternatives like type_info and so on ……
}

int main()
{
    next((char) CHAR_MAX);
    next((unsigned char) UCHAR_MAX);
    next((short) SHRT_MAX);
    next((unsigned short) USHRT_MAX);
    next((int) INT_MAX);
    next((unsigned int) UINT_MAX);
    next((bool) 1);                     // warning: use of an operand of type 'bool' in 'operator++' is deprecated

    return 0;
}
```

- results :

```
c : 127 + 1 = -128 (converted to ASCII value)
h : 255 + 1 = 0 (converted to ASCII value)
s : 32767 + 1 = -32768
t : 65535 + 1 = 0
i : 2147483647 + 1 = -2147483648
j : 4294967295 + 1 = 0
b : 1 + 1 = 1
```

This is an advanced code from my previous one using overloading similar functions for each data type(so shame, so it should be secret).

But now I have more question if I can compress the series of `next()` in `main()` more. I think it seems to require **a container that can have various typed data; for example, {short 1, int 10, long long 100}**.

Thank you for your advices & above all, take care of your health.

Comment: You seem to be learning C++ the wrong way. Your terminology seems wrong and confusing. The question is very unclear. I have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: Well, I meant to find some efficient way more than using `next()` repeatably. So I thought, if there is a container that can have various typed elements, I could easily substitute it in `for` loop.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it sounds like you want a `std::tuple`, and then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387354/template-tuple-calling-a-function-on-each-element) to call a function for each element of the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I have no idea what are you asking so I try to answer some related questions and hope this will help :)

To find a maximum value of a type `T`, use `numeric_limits<T>::max()` function instead of macros. This way you can only specify the type to call your function:

```
next<char>();
next<unsigned char>();
next<short>();
...
```

In the function `next` I can see how you handle `char` types in a special way. There is a neat trick that saves you from using `if`. Expression `+a` (unary plus) triggers integer promotion and thus will yield you at least type `int`, which is properly printable as a number. So you can rewrite `next` like this:

```
template <class T>
void next()
{
  T a = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
  T b = a + 1;
  std::cout << typeid(T).name() << " : " << +a << " + 1 = " << +b << std::endl;
}
```

Answering your original question, now when you got rid of macros in the calls of `next` you can "iterate" on the types to call it with. In c++ if you need a "collection of types" `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, you usually use `std::tuple<T1, T2, T3>`. However, in this particular case where you don't have to store this "collection" anywhere, it is actually easier to go with variadic templates and fold expressions:

```
template<class... Ts>
void print() {
    (next<Ts>(), ...);
}

int main()
{
  print<char, unsigned char, short, int>();
}
```

Note how expression `(next<Ts>(), ...);` expands into `(next<char>(), next<unsigned char>(), next<short>(), next<int>());`. This is a number of calls separated by operator comma.

As a final point, using `++a` or `a+1` to find a "next" number is incorrect, since overflowing signed integer types is undefined behavior. You won't necessarily get expected results.