# Can I iterate over a C++11 std::tuple with openmp?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, openmp, stdtuple

I have the following code given to iterate over `std::tuple`. The code is from here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple).

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename FuncT, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
for_each(std::tuple<Tp...> &, FuncT) // Unused arguments are given no names.
{ }

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename FuncT, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
for_each(std::tuple<Tp...>& t, FuncT& f)
{
    f(std::get<I>(t));
    for_each<I + 1, FuncT, Tp...>(t, f);
}
```

Now, I would like to execute this `for_each` loop with openmp, in the same way I can use openmp on `for`. Is there a trick to make this possible?

Note: You can modify the above code or use any other version of your own `for_each`.

Comment: I don't see a `for_each` "loop". I see recursion, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think it is okay to say that recursion is, in some abstract sense, a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++11 template syntax is highly alien to me, but recursive problems such as this one are best made parallel using explicit OpenMP tasks:

```
template<std::size_t I = 0, typename FuncT, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
for_each(std::tuple<Tp...>& t, FuncT& f)
{
    #pragma omp task firstprivate(I) shared(t,f)
    {
        f(std::get<I>(t));
    }
    for_each<I + 1, FuncT, Tp...>(t, f);
}

...

// Proper usage
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    for_each(...);
}
```

The important part is to have the top level call to `for_each` in a `single` construct inside a `parallel` region. Thus only a single thread will call `for_each`, which in turn will result in `f(std::get<I>(t));` being queued for later execution as an explicit task. The other threads, while waiting at the implicit barrier at the end of the `single` construct, will start pulling tasks from the task queue and execute them in parallel until the queue is empty. The sharing classes of all variables used by the task are given explicitly for clarity.

The objects that `t` and `f` reference should be shared and the references themselves (basically the pointers that implement the references) should be firstprivate. On the other side, the OpenMP standard prohibits reference types from being firstprivate and different compiler vendors tend to implement the standard differently. Intel C++ Compiler accepts the following code and it gives the correct results inside the task but the referenced variable is privatised (which is wrong):

```cpp
void f(int& p)
{
   #pragma omp task
   {
      cout << "p = " << p << endl;
      p = 3;
      cout << "p' = " << p << endl;
   }
}

void f1()
{
   int i = 5;

   #pragma omp parallel
   {
      #pragma omp single
      f(i);
   }
   cout << "i = " << i << endl;
}
```

PGI's compiler gives the correct result and does not privatise `i`. On the other side GCC correctly determines that `p` should be `firstprivate` but then runs into the prohibition in the standard and gives a compile-time error.

If one modifies the task to read:

```cpp
#pragma omp task shared(p)
{
    ...
}
```

it works correctly with GCC but the task prints wrong initial value of `p` and then causes a segmentation fault with both Intel C++ Compiler and PGI's C++ compiler.

Go figure!

Comment: Thanks! I can not compile [this code](http://pastebin.com/3jzNMCpu) , however :( . The compiler complains about the firstprivate, and I think you said `I` was not the problem? What could be wrong?

Comment: As fas as my knowledge on C++ templates goes, template arguments such as `I` are treated kind of like literal constants and not as variables, therefore `I` should not be put in `firstprivate` (or in any kind of data sharing clause).