# How to iterate through std::tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, tuples, template-meta-programming

Any better solution than manually writing a utility like this?

```
template < size_t > struct SizeT { };

template < typename TupleType, typename ActionType >
inline void TupleForEach( TupleType& tuple, ActionType action )
{
    TupleForEach( tuple, action, SizeT<std::tuple_size<TupleType>::value>() );
}

template < typename TupleType, typename ActionType >
inline void TupleForEach( TupleType& tuple, ActionType action, SizeT<0> ) { }

template < typename TupleType, typename ActionType, size_t N >
inline void TupleForEach( TupleType& tuple, ActionType action, SizeT<N> )
{
    TupleForEach( tuple, action, SizeT<N-1>() );
    action( std::get<N-1>( tuple ) );
}
```

To be used like this:

```
std::tuple<char, int, double> tt;
TupleForEach( tt, (boost::lambda::_1 = 5) );
```

Comment: What are your criteria for "better"?

Comment: @Casey -- A library implementation in `std` or `boost`; if not, then an implementation with less code then this; or maybe there is an issue in this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there are several answers provided in a [previous, related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple) (and the one you provide yourself), my initial impression is that the need to iterate over the tuple may be a reflection of a poor design.

As you know, the reason why we cannot iterate over a `std::tuple` using standard C++ algorithms is because `std::tuple` does not fulfill the [`Container` concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container). And, precisely, it does not fulfill such concept because `std::tuple`s do not have a `value_type` (they are heterogeneous). I know that you used a tuple because you did not want to create your own polymorphic type and store it in an standard container (e.g., `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>>`). This gave you a quick gain. But that also means that you voluntarily gave up the advantages of `Container`s.

It may work, but it somehow feels forced and unnatural: if you need container semantics, why not use a container? If you need polymorphic semantics, why not use a polymorphic type?

Probably I'm exaggerating, but this is my initial impression.

Comment: The reason why I did't created a polymorphic base class for types in the tuple isn't a whim :) These types are from kind of third-party, so who uses them, for sure, is not necessarily the one who maintains them. These types, however, share a common concept, thus some operations are valid for each of them, so the one who stores a bunch of objects of these types, might want to perform such operations over that objects.

Comment: Moreover, consider a tuple of `char`, `int` and `double`. Or a tuple of some pointers. In the first case there is e.g. a valid operation of setting the tuple members to zero, and in the second case there is e.g. a valid operation of setting the tuple members to `nullptr`, but for sure in C++ it is a kind of nonsense to consider a base class for all arithmetic types or a base class for all pointer types.