# Efficient way to translate a c++ pod struct into its equivalent Python struct representation

Tags: python, c++, metaprogramming

I've used a bit of metaprogramming (with metal and pfr) +  [Converting Tuple to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436406/converting-tuple-to-string)
to map a c++ pod struct into its equivalent python struct representation (padding not accounted for yet but this is a separate step)

So my questions is, how can I do this better? I'm ok moving forward with this but it seems there must be some way I can simplify this code. Any suggestions?

Code here:
https://github.com/Kubiyak/pybuffer_container/blob/master/meta_example.cpp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I would do what you suggest but when I try to enter my code sample (which is on github) in CodeReview.SE it shows up quite garbled.  If you can show me how to submit a link to the code on github or write the code better in SE I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a good guide:
I will take the solution based on std::apply w/ c
[How can you iterate over the elements of an std::tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/how-can-you-iterate-over-the-elements-)
of-an-stdtuple

That cleaned up my code significantly. How can I delete this q? I cannot find the delete button for it.