# Workaround for lack of expression SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I'm trying to call a function for each value in a `std::tuple`, of course there is no way to iterate a tuple and so I've resorted to using the template techniques discussed in [iterate over tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple/6894436#6894436)

However, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and it does not support expression SFINAE, so that code won't work. I've tried to partially specialize the templates based on a constant numbers (e.g 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0), but haven't had any success. I'm certainly no template expert, and so I was hoping somebody could help me out. My expression SFINAE code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

struct ArgPush {
    void push(bool x) {}
    void push(int x) {}
    void push(double x) {}
    void push(const char* x) {}
    void push(const std::string& x) {}

    template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
    inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
        push_tuple(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
    { }

    template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
    inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
        push_tuple(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
    {
        push(std::get<I>(t));
        push_tuple<I + 1, Tp...>(t);
    }
};

int main() {
    ArgPush().push_tuple(std::make_tuple(1,2,3,4));
    ArgPush().push_tuple(std::make_tuple("hello", "msvc makes me sad", 4, true));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC doesn't like the equality comparisons being made within the `enable_if`. So move these out from there to a helper template. Then your code compiles on VS2013.

```
template<std::size_t I, typename... Tp>
struct comparator
{
    static const bool value = (I < sizeof...(Tp));
};

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<!comparator<I, Tp...>::value>::type
    push_tuple(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
{ }

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<comparator<I, Tp...>::value>::type
    push_tuple(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
{
    push(std::get<I>(t));
    push_tuple<I + 1, Tp...>(t);
}
```

Comment: I've never used VS2013, but from what I read here, it seems rubbish. How come anybody want's to use it if there is clang for free?

Comment: @Walter Put another way, you're asking why do people want to use a compiler that is best suited for targeting an OS with over 90% market share, does that answer your question? :-) clang doesn't work on Windows (and don't link me to their Windows builds, it's unusable for anything other than toy programs). MinGW is an option, and I use that myself for personal projects, but most people are forced to go with the compiler their employer chooses.

Comment: @Walter Also, even though I hate how lacking it is, I will also admit that if you stay within the confines it imposes on you, VS has a much better user experience than screwing around with gdb and such.

Comment: @Walter I've never got clang to work correctly on Windows, and the rest is most or less as Praetorian says; it works well most of the time. Also, thanks Praetorian - works great. I'll certainly be adding this to my MSVC toolbox!

Answer (score 2):

You can partial specialization instead of SFINAE:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct helper
{
    template <typename T>
    static void push(T&& v)
    {
        // do something
    }
    template <typename ...Types>
    static void push_tuple(const std::tuple<Types...>& t)
    {
        push(std::get<sizeof...(Types) - N>(t));
        helper<N - 1>::push_tuple(t);
    }
};

template <>
struct helper<0>
{
    template <typename ...Types>
    static void push_tuple(const std::tuple<Types...>&)
    {
        // nothing (end of iteration)
    }
};

template <typename ...Types>
void push_tuple(const std::tuple<Types...>& t)
{
    helper<sizeof...(Types)>::push_tuple(t);
}
```