# What SFINAE tricks can I safely use on all MSVC >= 2013?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, visual-c++, sfinae

In Qt I had the brilliant (cough, cough) idea to start defining overloads of `qHash` (the hashing function used for QHash, one of Qt's associative containers) for Standard Library datatypes: `std::basic_string`, `std::shared_ptr` and the like.

There could be a shortcut for this process: instead of chasing "any Standard Library type that could be used as a key in QHash" and adding a `qHash` overload for it, I could just define `qHash` automatically if the type has a `std::hash` specialization for it (reasonably assuming that we don't want to do more than what the Standard Library does in this process).

That is, I could implement something like this using expression SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
auto qHash(const T &t) -> decltype(std::hash<T>()(t)) 
{ 
    return std::hash<T>()(t); 
}
```

Unfortunately, although Qt demands a C++11 compiler, expression SFINAE is *not allowed anywhere* because MSVC does not fully support it (at the time of this writing: all MSVC versions, up to and including VS15 preview 5. Anyhow, Qt must support all the way back to 2013).

Hence, the question: is there a way to do the same, in a way that

1. does not use expression SFINAE
2. is guaranteed to work on all MSVC versions >= 2013?

I was thinking a plain good ol' C++98 SFINAE construction via `enable_if` and the like, but other SO answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097911/workaround-for-lack-of-expression-sfinae)) make me think that MSVC 2013 may miscompile that too, so the result becomes unacceptable again.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/02/partial-support-for-expression-sfinae-in-vs-2015-update-1/

Comment: Try tag dispatching.  Have your `qHash` tag-dispatch on "can I `std::hash<T>`" to either an implementation that uses `std::hash`, or one that does not.  Repeat for each thing you are testing for.

Comment: You can SFINAE on `std::hash::result_type` i think, which by definition for the std-provided specializations of `std::hash` is always `std::size_t`. That should work even with primitive compilers.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/expression-sfinae-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3/

Comment: @HansPassant: that's about MSVC 2015, not 2013. Neither of them claim expression SFINAE support, so we can't use it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you need expression SFINAE for this, something along these lines should work.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::hash<T>::result_type qHash(const T &t) 
{ 
     return std::hash<T>()(t); 
}
```

Or pretty much any approach that does SFINAE on `hash::result_type`. Unfortunately for you, `hash::result_type` is deprecated in C++17, but you can still `#ifdef` this code for MSVC 2013.

Comment: Ha, of course, I was reading N4594 and was finding *no* mentions of `std::hash<T>::result_type`...

Comment: @peppe Ta-Daa, I think you've got your answer :)