# Deriving type of tuple of nested types of another tuple's types

Tags: c++, types, nested, tuples

I have a class like this:

```
#include <tuple>

// Models is supposed to be a tuple<class... Classes>
template<class Models>
class MyClass
{
    std::tuple<
        std::tuple_element<0,Models>::type::NestedType,
        std::tuple_element<1,Models>::type::NestedType,
        std::tuple_element<2,Models>::type::NestedType
        > nestedTypedTuple;
};
```

Currently `nestedTypedTuple` is of fixed size of 3 elements, which is too small for larger-sized `Models` and won't work at all for smaller-sized `Models`. I'd like to define it in a more generic way, so that its declaration worked for any number of elements in `Models`. It seems using the ways given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple) for iterating over tuple won't work because I need to derive a type, not call a function here.

What would be a working approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option #1

```
template <class Models> class MyClass; // leave undefined

template <class... Ts>
class MyClass<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    std::tuple<typename Ts::NestedType...> nestedTypedTuple;
};
```

#### Option #2

```
template <class Models>
class MyClass
{
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    static std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<Is, Models>::type::NestedType...> helper(std::index_sequence<Is...>);
    using NestedTypedTuple = decltype(helper(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Models>::value>{}));

    NestedTypedTuple nestedTypedTuple;
};
```