# Variadic Template - find the minimum in a tuple of objects of the same type

Tags: templates, c++11, variadic

I was trying to solve the following exercise from cracking the code Cracking the Code interview (pag. 81):

> An animal shelter holds only dogs and cats, and operates on a strictly
>   "first in, first out" basis. People must adopt either the "oldest"
>   (based on arrival time) of all animals at the shelter, or they can
>   select whether they would prefer a dog or a cat (and will receive the
>   oldest animal of that type). They cannot select which specific animal
>   they would like. Create the data structures to maintain this system
>   and implement operations such as enqueue, dequeueAny, dequeueDog and
>   dequeueCat.You may use the built-in LinkedList data structure.

With only two animals is easy and I managed to do it implementing a class Shelter that keeps two separate queues, one for cats and dogs and storing the time at which the animal is enqueued. However, I was wondering how to generalise it to a generic number of animals, without the need to actually change the interface of the class Shelter. I thought that variadic template could help, but I cannot understand how to write a the code/syntax to declare the different Queues for the different type of animals.

First is this possible? Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks to suggestions, I think I made some progress:

```
template <typename A>
struct Animal {
    string hello(void) {return A::hello(); }
    string name;
};


class GenericAnimal {
    public: 
        virtual string hello(void) {return "????";}
};

class Dog : public GenericAnimal {

    public:
        virtual string hello (void) {return "waf waf";}
};
class Cat : public GenericAnimal {
    public:
        virtual string hello (void) {return "miao miao";}
};


template <typename ...A>
class Shelter {
    public:
        Shelter():time(0){}
        template <typename T>
        void getQueueFor( queue< tuple<int, Animal<T>> > &q ){
            q= get< queue< tuple<int, Animal<T>> > > (shelterQueues);
        }

        template <typename T>
        void addAnimals(Animal<T> &a) {
            tuple<int, Animal<T>> aa  (time++, a);
            (get< queue< tuple<int, Animal<T>> > > (shelterQueues)).push(aa);
        } 

        GenericAnimal& getOldestAnimal (void) {
            size_t size= std::tuple_size<decltype(shelterQueues)>::value;
            for(size_t i=0; i < size; i++) {
                get<0>(shelterQueues);
                cout << i << ",";
            } 
            cout << endl;

        }

    private:
        int time;
        tuple< queue< tuple <int, Animal<A>> >... > shelterQueues;
};
```

I am able to enque cats and dog now.
Now, I was trying to implement dequeAny(), that should return the oldest animal in the system, but I got stuck. Basically, the problem is that I have to iterate over the tuple of queues and see which head has the lowest time. Looking around I found  how to iterate over a tuple [iterate-over-tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple). The problem is that even if I manage to identify it, let's call it K, then I need to do get(myQueue) and this should not work because K is not known at compile time. Am I wrong? 
Any idea if it is possible and how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: User asks for `Shelter<A,B,C>`, in class `Shelter<T...>` you can store a `tuple<queue<T>...>`.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to have a single queue<boost::variant<T...>>.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `std::tuple`. As mentioned in the comments, a `tuple<queue<T>>` fits your use-case. A useful thing about tuples is that it lets you query an element by type, as long as the types it is templated on are unique. Here's an example:

```
template <typename ... Animals>
class AnimalQueue
{
public:
template <typename T>
queue<T> GetQueueFor(){return get<queue<T>>(mQueues);}

tuple<queue<Animals>...> mQueues;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is one of the things I was wondering to use and I got stuck, because in all the examples I saw with tuple, it seems you need to know in which position each type is declared, so when I do the addAnimal(cat), how I get the right queue? The way I saw tuple are accessed is using get<k>. Is there any other way? am I missing something ?

Comment: @Kude `tuple::get` has overloads which take the type as well. Take a look at 4-6 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get). So, assuming the class is called `cat`, with the above code snippet, you can do `GetQueueFor<cat>()` to get the `queue<cat>` element out of the `tuple`.

Comment: Getting tuple elements by type is a new feature in C++14, though, so your compiler might not support it yet.