# Visual studio - workaround error c2770 on std::enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

taking the answer from here : [iterate over tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple) regarding printing `std::tuple` components, here is the code :

```
template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
 typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
print(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
{ }

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
 typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
    print(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
{
    std::cout << std::get<I>(t) << std::endl;
    print <i, Tp...> (t);
}
```

this compiles and works perfectly on GCC, but fails to compile on VC++ (I use visual studio 2013). the error I'm gettting :

```
Error   4   error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::enable_if<I==1,void>::type print(const std::tuple<_Types1...> &)' 
Error   3   error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'std::enable_if<I<1,void>::type print(const std::tuple<_Types1...> &)'
```

appearntly there is a documented bug on C2770 when using `std::enable_if` with explicit template-arguments. some developers recommended using `const int` as pre-argument for the template as

```
const int i = I+1;
print<i,Tp...>(t);
```

but this does not work either. 
there were other solutions also such as use some macros , but they fail too.
does someone have a work around it ? I searched for a solution but found none that actually works.
thanks.

Comment: Works for me in VS2015 RC. Release is (hopefully) soon, so toolchain upgrade could be non-standard, but viable option too. (Not even mentioning `constexpr`, faster compilation and linkage etc. in VS2015)

Comment: thank gos they fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use one of the following:

- using *decrementing* recursion and (partial) specialization:

  ```
  namespace detail
  {
      template <std::size_t N>
      struct printer
      {
          template <typename TUPLE>
          void operator () (const TUPLE& t) const
          {
              printer<N - 1>{}(t);
              std::cout << std::get<N - 1>(t) << std::endl;
          }
      };

      template <>
      struct printer<0>
      {
          template <typename TUPLE>
          void operator () (const TUPLE& t) const {}
      };

  }


  template <typename ... Ts>
  void print(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
  {
      detail::printer<sizeof...(Ts)>{}(t);
  }
  ```
- or using `index_sequence`

  ```
  #if 1 // Not in C++11
  #include <cstdint>

  template <std::size_t...> struct index_sequence {};

  template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
  struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

  template <std::size_t... Is>
  struct make_index_sequence<0u, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...>{};

  #endif

  namespace detail
  {

      template <std::size_t... Is, typename TUPLE>
      void print(const TUPLE& t, index_sequence<Is...>)
      {
          int dummy[] = {0, ((std::cout << std::get<Is>(t) << std::endl), 0)...};
          (void) dummy; // To remove warning about unused variable.
      }

  }

  template <typename ... Ts>
  void print(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
  {
      detail::print(t, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)> {});
  }
  ```

Comment: I didn't tried the second code snippet but the first defintly works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To retain the structure of the original code given in the question, the following workaround works for me in MSVC 2013:

Define the following helper:

```
// workaround for msvc `sizeof...(Tp)` not working
template<typename... Tp>
struct sizeof_pack___ { static const std::size_t value = sizeof...(Tp); };
```

Then replace the two occurrences of `sizeof...(Tp)` with `sizeof_pack___<Tp...>::value`.

The final code would look like this:

```
template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
 typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof_pack___<Tp...>::value, void>::type
    print(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
{ }

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
 typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof_pack___<Tp...>::value, void>::type
    print(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
{
    std::cout << std::get<I>(t) << std::endl;
    print <i, Tp...> (t);
}
```