# treat non-polymorphic objects in a polymorphic way with no performance overhead

Tags: c++, performance, polymorphism

This question is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314193/iterating-over-different-types/34314624) which was asking about calling the same method on dissimilar types when those types are known at compile time.

This got me thinking. Suppose I had dissimilar non-polymorphic types but I wanted use them polymorphically. Furthermore, I want to do that without ever invoking `new` and `delete` since these are known performance bottlenecks.

How would I do that?

Note this is a Q&A style question. I have provided the answer I came up with. This is not to attract upvotes (although that's always nice), but to share the insight I gained while working on this problem.

Other answers are certainly invited. The more knowledge we share, the better we all become.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was in-part inspired by the excellent work done by Beman Dawes on the boost::system_error library.

I learned the idea of static polymorphism by studying his fantastic work, which has now become part of the c++11 standard. Beman, if you ever read this please take a bow.

The other source of inspiration was the excellent talk called [Inheritance is the base class of evil](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil) by the truly gifted Sean Parent. I thoroughly recommend every c++ developer to watch it.

So enough of that, here's (my) solution:

problem:

I have a number of UI object types that are not polymorphic (for performance reasons). However, sometimes I wish to call `show()` or `hide()` methods on groups of these objects.

Furthermore I want the references or pointers to these objects to be polymorphic.

*Furthermore* not all the objects even support the `show()` and `hide()` methods, but that shouldn't matter.

*Furthermore* the runtime performance overhead should be as close to zero as possible.

Many thanks to @Jarod42 for suggesting a less complicated constructor for `showable`.

my solutuion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

// define an object that is able to call show() on another object, or emit a warning if that
// method does not exist
class call_show {

    // deduces the presence of the method on the target by declaring a function that either
    // returns a std::true_type or a std::false_type.
    // note: we never define the function. we just want to deduce the theoretical return type

    template<class T> static auto test(T* p) -> decltype(p->show(), std::true_type());
    template<class T> static auto test(...) -> decltype(std::false_type());

    // define a constant based on the above test using SFNAE
    template<class T>
    static constexpr bool has_method = decltype(test<T>(nullptr))::value;

public:

    // define a function IF the method exists on UIObject
    template<class UIObject>
    auto operator()(UIObject* p) const
    -> std::enable_if_t< has_method<UIObject>, void >
    {
        p->show();
    }

    // define a function IF NOT the method exists on UIObject
    // Note, we could put either runtime error handling (as below) or compile-time handling
    // by putting a static_assert(false) in the body of this function
    template<class UIObject>
    auto operator()(UIObject* p) const
    -> std::enable_if_t< not has_method<UIObject>, void >
    {
        std::cout << "warning: show is not defined for a " << typeid(UIObject).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

// ditto for the hide method
struct call_hide
{
    struct has_method_ {
        template<class T> static auto test(T* p) -> decltype(p->hide(), std::true_type());
        template<class T> static auto test(...) -> decltype(std::false_type());
    };

    template<class T>
    static constexpr bool has_method = decltype(has_method_::test<T>(nullptr))::value;

    template<class UIObject>
    auto operator()(UIObject* p) const
    -> std::enable_if_t< has_method<UIObject>, void >
    {
        p->hide();
    }

    template<class UIObject>
    auto operator()(UIObject* p) const
    -> std::enable_if_t< not has_method<UIObject>, void >
    {
        std::cout << "warning: hide is not defined for a " << typeid(UIObject).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

// define a class to hold non-owning REFERENCES to any object
// if the object has an accessible show() method then this reference's show() method will cause
// the object's show() method to be called. Otherwise, error handling will be invoked.
//
class showable
{
    // define the POLYMORPHIC CONCEPT of a thing being showable.
    // In this case, the concept requires that the thing has a show() and a hide() method
    // note that there is no virtual destructor. It's not necessary because we will only ever
    // create one model of this concept for each type, and it will be a static object
    struct concept {
        virtual void show(void*) const = 0;
        virtual void hide(void*) const = 0;
    };

    // define a MODEL of the CONCEPT for a given type of UIObject
    template<class UIObject>
    struct model final
    : concept
    {
        // user-provided constructor is necessary because of static construction (below)
        model() {};

        // implement the show method by indirection through a temporary call_show() object
        void show(void* p) const override {
            // the static_cast is provably safe
            call_show()(static_cast<UIObject*>(p));
        }

        // ditto for hide
        void hide(void* p) const override {
            call_hide()(static_cast<UIObject*>(p));
        }
    };

    // create a reference to a static MODEL of the CONCEPT for a given type of UIObject
    template<class UIObject>
    static const concept* make_model()
    {
        static const model<UIObject> _;
        return std::addressof(_);
    }

    // this reference needs to store 2 pointers:

    // first a pointer to the referent object
    void * _object_reference;

    // and secondly a pointer to the MODEL appropriate for this kind of object
    const concept* _call_concept;

    // we use pointers because they allow objects of the showable class to be trivially copyable
    // much like std::reference_wrapper<>

public:

    // PUBLIC INTERFACE

    // special handling for const references because internally we're storing a void* and therefore
    // have to cast away constness
    template<class UIObject>
    showable(const UIObject& object)
    : _object_reference(const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void *>(std::addressof(object))))
    , _call_concept(make_model<UIObject>())
    {}

    template<class UIObject>
    showable(UIObject& object)
    : _object_reference(reinterpret_cast<void *>(std::addressof(object)))
    , _call_concept(make_model<UIObject>())
    {}

    // provide a show() method.
    // note: it's const because we want to be able to call through a const reference
    void show() const {
        _call_concept->show(_object_reference);
    }

    // provide a hide() method.
    // note: it's const because we want to be able to call through a const reference
    void hide() const {
        _call_concept->hide(_object_reference);
    }
};


//
// TEST CODE
//

// a function to either call show() or hide() on a vector of `showable`s
void show_or_hide(const std::vector<showable>& showables, bool show)
{
    for (auto& s : showables)
    {
        if (show) {
            s.show();
        }
        else {
            s.hide();
        }
    }
}

// a function to transform any group of object references into a vector of `showable` concepts
template<class...Objects>
auto make_showable_vector(Objects&&...objects)
{
    return std::vector<showable> {
        showable(objects)...
    };
}


int main()
{
    // declare some types that may or may not support show() and hide()
    // and create some models of those types

    struct Window{
        void show() {
            std::cout << __func__ << " Window\n";
        }
        void hide() {
            std::cout << __func__ << " Window\n";
        }

    } w1, w2, w3;

    struct Widget{

        // note that Widget does not implement show()

        void hide() {
            std::cout << __func__ << " Widget\n";
        }

    } w4, w5, w6;

    struct Toolbar{
        void show()
        {
            std::cout << __func__ << " Toolbar\n";
        }

        // note that Toolbar does not implement hide()

    } t1, t2, t3;

    struct Nothing {
        // Nothing objects don't implement any of the functions in which we're interested
    } n1, n2, n3;

    // create some polymorphic references to some of the models
    auto v1 = make_showable_vector(w3, w4, n1, w5, t1);
    auto v2 = make_showable_vector(n3, w1, w2, t2, w6);

    // perform some polymorphic actions on the non-polymorphic types
    std::cout << "showing my UI objects\n";
    show_or_hide(v1, true);
    show_or_hide(v2, true);

    std::cout << "\nhiding my UI objects\n";
    show_or_hide(v2, false);
    show_or_hide(v1, false);

    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
showing my UI objects
show Window
warning: show is not defined for a Z4mainE6Widget
warning: show is not defined for a Z4mainE7Nothing
warning: show is not defined for a Z4mainE6Widget
show Toolbar
warning: show is not defined for a Z4mainE7Nothing
show Window
show Window
show Toolbar
warning: show is not defined for a Z4mainE6Widget

hiding my UI objects
warning: hide is not defined for a Z4mainE7Nothing
hide Window
hide Window
warning: hide is not defined for a Z4mainE7Toolbar
hide Widget
hide Window
hide Widget
warning: hide is not defined for a Z4mainE7Nothing
hide Widget
warning: hide is not defined for a Z4mainE7Toolbar
```

Comment: Any reason to have `vector<showable>` instead of a `tuple` and iterate over the tuple ?

Comment: BTW, why not use the 2 overloads `showable(const UIObject& object)`/`showable(UIObject& object)` instead of SFINAE on `is_const`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes. it's to demonstrate that the `showable` reference is polymorphic, so functions can be written in terms of the `showable` concept, for example you can now pass an arbitrary run-time collection of showables to a function. Those showables will be referring to type-erased non-poly objects.

Comment: Your `void*` is unneeded, you may put member directly inside model (you have to remove the static singleton). If the `static` was to avoid allocation, you may still do a placement new.

Comment: @Jarod42  we did that how would we point to 2 different referents of the same type? We'd need a memory allocation, surely?

Comment: In fact, you have almost reimplemented virtual function machinery inside your smart reference class. In your case the `concept` objects serve as virtual function tables, they are global, allocated on "per type" basis. And you have to store VFT pointer in a reference, because you are not storing it in the object itself.
The code is quite large to write it for every set of methods you want to make polymorphic in a program =) But anyway, the idea of polymorphic references is cool. I wonder if it were discussed in the area of C++ standard or boost.

Comment: @stgatilov the code is large but quite boilerplate-like. I'm pretty sure an afternoon's work could boil it down to a class template that we simply specialise with a traits class for each method we want to support.