# Is it possible to call a member function for every type in a tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, tuples, sfinae

```
namespace details {
template <std::size_t I = 0, typename Tuple, typename Function, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<I == std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value, void>::type ForEach(Tuple &t, Function f, Args &... args) {}

template <std::size_t I = 0, typename Tuple, typename Function, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<(I < std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value), void>::type ForEach(Tuple &t, Function f, Args &... args) {
    f(std::get<I>(t), args...);
    ForEach<I + 1>(t, f, args...);
}
}
```

An implementation for ForEach functionality for all types of a tuple is above. It calls `f(tuple_type, args...)`

However I want something like `tuple_type.f(args...)` where f and args are template arguments.

f would be a member function of all the types in the tuple, taking args... as arguments.

```
template <typename... Types>
class TupleManager {
    std::tuple<Types...> t;
    template <typename Function, typename... Args>
    void ForEach(Function f, Args& ... args) {
         details::ForEach<>(t, f, args...);
    }
}
```

Clarification: f needs to be a member function, i.e a function that takes the same name for all types in the tuple.

Eg:

```
struct A {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "A's foo\n";
    }
};
struct B : A {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "B's foo\n";
    }
};

struct C : A {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "C's foo\n";
    }
};
```

But now I can't pass `foo`. Passing `&A::foo` print's A's foo. The requirement is to print A'foo for object of A in the tuple, B's foo for object of B in the tuple, and C's foo for object of C in the tuple.

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qCBTWcoxNcJuYku0)

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  "Something like" with *no description of what features of what you typed you actually want* is not very clear.  What "like" that do you want, what do you need, etc?  You want `f` to be between `tuple_type` and `args...`?  You want to use exactly that syntax, where `f` happens to be the name of a common member function?  You want exactly that punctuation?

Comment: Think about how to call your function... `ForEach(myTuple, &C::foo)`...

Comment: Change `f(std::get<I>(t), args...);` to `std::get<I>(t).f(args...)` and see Jarod's comment.

Comment: Have provided a Wandbox link. PAssing &C::foo isn't viable. What is C? C is a type of the tuple. It's not known while calling ForEach. Only's foo is known, or rather that the name foo.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of `std::for_each` is in its disassociation of function application (on the elements of the range) from iteration (of the range). As such, one doesn't pass the arguments of the call to `std::for_each` (except for the callee itself that is already passed via the range). Having that in mind, you might want to consider using a different version of `for_each` that is closer to the `std` one. Check this one for example: [iterate over tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple/6894436#6894436).

If you're up to a generalisation, you may want to use [Jonathan Müller's `tuple_iterator`](https://foonathan.net/blog/2017/03/01/tuple-iterator.html). That enables application `std` algorithms on `std::tuple`s just as if `std::tuple` were a `std` container. In particular, you can use `std::for_each` for your desirable iteration.