# Convert template function to generic lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, enable-if

I'd like to pass templated functions around as if they were generic lambdas, however this does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <utility> 


// for_each with std::tuple
// (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894436/1583122)
template<std::size_t I = 0, typename FuncT, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
for_each(std::tuple<Tp...> &, FuncT)
{}

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename FuncT, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
for_each(std::tuple<Tp...>& t, FuncT f) {
    f(std::get<I>(t));
    for_each<I + 1, FuncT, Tp...>(t, f);
}

// my code
template<class T> auto
print(const std::vector<T>& v) -> void {
    for (const auto& e : v) {
        std::cout << e << "\t";
    }
}

struct print_wrapper {
    template<class T>
    auto operator()(const std::vector<T>& v) {
        print(v);
    }
};

auto print_gen_lambda = [](const auto& v){ print(v); };

auto print_gen_lambda_2 = []<class T>(const std::vector<T>& v){ print(v); }; // proposal P0428R1, gcc extension in c++14/c++17

int main() {
     std::tuple<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<std::string>> t = { {42,43},{3.14,2.7},{"Hello","World"}};
    for_each(t, print); // case 1: error: template argument deduction/substitution failed: couldn't deduce template parameter 'FuncT'
    for_each(t, print_wrapper()); // case 2: ok
    for_each(t, print_gen_lambda); // case 3: ok
    for_each(t, print_gen_lambda_2); // case 4: ok
}
```

Note that case 2 and 4 are strictly equivalent. Case 3 is more general but unconstrained (this is a problem for me). I think that case 1 should be treated equivalently to cases 2 and 4 by the language, however this is not the case.

- Is there a proposal to implicitly convert a template function to a generic constrained lambda (case 2/4)? If no, is there a fundamental language reason that prevents from doing so?
- As of now, I have to use case 2, which is quite cumbersome.

  - case 4: not c++14-compliant, even if should be standard in [c++20](https://herbsutter.com/2017/07/15/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-toronto/), and still not perfect (verbose since you create a lambda that fundamentally does not add any information).
  - case 3: is unconstrained, but I rely (not shown here) on substitution failure for calls to "print" with non-"vector" arguments (P0428R1 mentions this problem). So I guess the subsidiary question is "Can I constrain a generic lambda with some enable_if tricks?"

Is there, in C++14/17/20, a very terse manner to enable the conversion from case 1 to case 2? I am even open to macro hacks.

Comment: To anyone who wonders, the problem stems from `print` not actually naming a function.

Comment: Yes. The trick is that template function are not types, whereas non-template classes with template member functions are just normal types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there, in C++14/17/20, a very terse manner to enable the conversion from case 1 to case 2? I am even open to macro hacks.

Yes.

```
// C++ requires you to type out the same function body three times to obtain
// SFINAE-friendliness and noexcept-correctness. That's unacceptable.
#define RETURNS(...) noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
     -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__){ return __VA_ARGS__; }

// The name of overload sets can be legally used as part of a function call -
// we can use a macro to create a lambda for us that "lifts" the overload set
// into a function object.
#define LIFT(f) [](auto&&... xs) RETURNS(f(::std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...))
```

You can then say:

```
for_each(t, LIFT(print));
```

---

> Is there a proposal to implicitly convert a template function to a generic constrained lambda?

Yes, look at [P0119](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0119r1.pdf) or [N3617](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3617.htm). Not sure about their status.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for. I am not sure I understand how the lambda is constrained though... Is it the `-> decltype(__VA_ARGS__)` ?

Comment: @Bérenger: yes, the `decltype` containing the body is constraining the lambda, as it's SFINAE-friendly.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I constrain a generic lambda with some enable_if tricks?

If all what you want is to constrain the types of the parameters of your generic lambda, you can do that with a couple of function declarations (no definition required) and a `static_assert` (so that you get a graceful message error at compile-time in case of failure). No macro at all around (they are so *C-ish*).

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<vector>
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>
#include<list>

template<template<typename...> class C, typename... A>
constexpr std::true_type spec(int, C<A...>);

template<template<typename...> class C, template<typename...> class T, typename... A>
constexpr std::false_type spec(char, T<A...>);

int main() {
    auto fn = [](auto&& v) {
        static_assert(decltype(spec<std::vector>(0, std::declval<std::decay_t<decltype(v)>>()))::value, "!");
        // ...
    };

    fn(std::vector<int>{});
    // fn(std::list<int>{});
    //fn(int{});
}
```

If you toggle the comments to the last lines, the `static_assert` will throw an error and the compilation will fail as expected.
See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vyDXY37f1DDSl74x).

---

Side note.

Of course you can reduce the boilerplate here:

```
static_assert(decltype(spec<std::vector>(0, std::declval<std::decay_t<decltype(v)>>()))::value, "!");
```

Add a variable template like the following one:

```
template<template<typename...> class C, typename T>
constexpr bool match = decltype(spec<C>(0, std::declval<std::decay_t<T>>()))::value;
```

Then use it in your `static_assert`s:

```
static_assert(match<std::vector, decltype(v)>, "!");
```

Pretty clear, isn't it?

---

Note.

In C++17 you'll be able to reduce even more the code required to do that by defining your lambda as:

```
auto fn = [](auto&& v) {
    if constexpr(match<std::vector, decltype(v)>) {
        print(v);
    }
};
```

See your example code running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4UqcGdZXUv12bdMC).

Comment: Yes it will throw an error, but it can't be used with SFINAE, see P0428R1 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0428r1.pdf)

Comment: Well, `match` is true if `v` is a vector. You can define a single `for_each` function and use that information directly within the lambda (in C++17 you can do that through `if constexpr`). The `static_assert` is part of an example code, you can remove it. :-)

Comment: @Bérenger [This](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4UqcGdZXUv12bdMC) is how your example would look like in C++17.