# Enforce parameter evaluation order while retaining lifetime of of expressions

Tags: c++, c++14, lifetime, temporary-objects

Given a macro `FOO` used like this:

```
std::string f1();
std::string f2();
FOO(f1().c_str(), f2().c_str());
```

Note: The type, `std::string` is only an example. `FOO` is generic and may not assume anything about types.

that is supposed to guarantee the order of evaluation of `f1()` and `f2()` by doing something like:

```
#define FOO(e1, e2) \
do {                \
    auto v1 = e1;   \
    auto v2 = e2;   \
    foo(e1, e2);    \
} while(0)
```

Edit: unfortunately `foo` can also be a template.

Unfortunately, that way the temporary returned by `f1` is deleted and the `c_str` becomes invalid for the call to `foo`.

Is there a way to guarantee the order of expression evaluation for macro parameters while retaining all temporary lifetimes?

Surely there are overall better ways to approach that, but I'm specifically curious if there is a way to do this without reasoning about each of the usages of that macro in a large code base. Further I want to avoid handling specific types (i.e. not preserving `const char*` with `strdup`).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058592/how-to-guarantee-order-of-argument-evaluation-when-calling-a-function-object

Comment: `#define FOO(e1, e2) [&](auto v1) { [&](auto v2) { foo(v1, v2); }(e2); }(e1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is trivial in C++17, using [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
#define FOO(...) std::apply(foo, decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(__VA_ARGS__)){__VA_ARGS__})
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/g/n3sCJz).

If you're using a pre-C++17 standard library, you can use the recipe for implementing `std::apply` at the above link.

If `foo` is a function template or an overload set, it can't be passed directly to `std::apply` so it has to be [wrapped in a polymorphic lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187335/convert-template-function-to-generic-lambda):

```
#define FOO(...) std::apply( \
    [](auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto) { return foo(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }, \
    decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(__VA_ARGS__)){__VA_ARGS__})
```

This works because the order of evaluation within `{}` braces is strict left-to-right. We use `std::forward_as_tuple` to determine the *type* of the tuple we want to pass to `apply`, but we construct it using list-initialization syntax.

If you're using a C++17 compiler with class template argument deduction, and don't need to worry about lvalue references, you could simplify this even further:

```
#define FOO(...) std::apply(foo, std::tuple{__VA_ARGS__})
```

Unfortunately, because the solution (without class template argument deduction) uses `decltype`, it won't work if the arguments involve lambda expressions. The only way I can see to make it work in this case is to use the sequencing between function arguments and function body, expanding `FOO(e1, e2)` to:

```
[&](auto&& p1) {
    return [&](auto&& p2) {
        return foo(std::forward<decltype(p1)>(p1), std::forward<decltype(p2)>(p2));
    }(e2);
}(e1)
```

This is actually possible using the incredible [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library:

```
#define FOO_IMPL_START(z,n,_) [&](auto&& p ## n) { return
#define FOO_IMPL_PARAM(z,n,_) std::forward<decltype(p ## n)>(p ## n)
#define FOO_IMPL_END(z,n,t) ; }(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(n,t))
#define FOO_IMPL(n,t) \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, FOO_IMPL_START, _) \
    foo(BOOST_PP_ENUM(n, FOO_IMPL_PARAM, _)) \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, FOO_IMPL_END, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REVERSE(t))
#define FOO(...) (FOO_IMPL(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/319d25ca87a459ed).

Comment: This doesn't keep around the temporaries like OP would like (not saying it's a good idea).

Comment: @TartanLlama they're preserved for the duration of the call, which is all OP needs.

Comment: oh my bad, I thought they were storing the pointers somewhere or something crazy like that.

Comment: It'd be nice if there was some slight modification to the latter syntax that supported forwarding, to avoid the hefty decltype in the first one

Comment: Unfortunately I have learned that `foo` can also be a template in the code, which seems to be a problem with `std::apply` *sigh*.

Comment: @Zulan that's OK, you need to lift it into a polymorphic lambda. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Woha, thanks alot! I tried a lambda but didn't get it right. Now it works in my small test, but the production code crashes gcc 7.1.1 with a segfault (and it's not just the stack limit). I'll try to make a distilled example as gcc bugreport.

Comment: I hate to say this. But in a dark corner of the production code, there is a lambda within the expression passed to `FOO(..., std::count_if(... , [](){}))` which gives a *lambda-expression in unevaluated context*. I'll try to instantiate a helper struct within the macro to pass in the `function`.

Comment: @Zulan Came up with a preprocessor-heavy nested-lambda solution.

Comment: As OP apparently doesn't care about the result (note the `do ... while(0)`), we can just use a class type whose constructor does the calling and list-initialize that from `{ lambda-wrapping-foo, __VA_ARGS__ }`

Answer (score 0):

Generalized solution:

```
struct Execute
{
    template <typename Func, typename ... Args>
    Execute(Func&& function, Args&& ... args)
    {
        std::forward<Func>(function)(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
    }
};

#define FOO(...)                            \
    do {                                    \
            Execute{foo, __VA_ARGS__};      \
    } while(0)

 FOO(f1().c_str(), f2().c_str()); // this will be evaluated in order from left to right
```

The reason why it has to work: evaluation order of braced-init-list is guaranteed.

C++11 Standard, 8.5.4/4:

> Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the
>   initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions
>   (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear...

Unlike the accepted solution it works with **C++11** without any shenanigans and do not need Boost.

Comment: If you give a minus, please be so kind to explain. This is such a stack-overflow style...

Comment: The declarations of f1 and f2 are outside the do...while, and you don't answer the question. You just say "what is the purpose of this code?" and suggest different code. That question should be a comment.

Comment: OK. I think OP wants the arguments to be any arbitrary expression involving a temporary , where the first one needs to be called before the second one. Your suggestion works for `std::string` only.

Comment: But my previous answers used to work for strings only

Comment: @DevNull the answer was completely changed since I made that comment