std::function to functions with default argument
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using MyFunctionAlias = std::function<void(int, double)>;

void exampleFunction(int value, double value2 = 3.14) {}

void exampleFunction2(int value, double value2) {}

int main() {
    MyFunctionAlias func = exampleFunction;

    // OK
    func(10, 2);

    // ERROR
    func(10);

    return 0;
}

The problem is that default arguments are not allowed in the declaration of the std::function object, so func must be invoked with all arguments.
In my application, I use MyFunctionAlias as member variable in different classes to have a generic type for various cases. In some classes, there are certain optional arguments. In those cases, I could simple provide dummy values for the optional arguments in the function call, but ideally I do not want to provide dummy values but call the function without the default arguments like above.
Is there a way to do this using function pointers?
There was a similar question here, but I think this solution only works when binding to always the same function -- I want to set func to different functions (func = exampleFunction2, func = exampleFunction3,...) depending on some run-time input.

Do you really need to use std::funtion?  You can get what you want with a lambda like auto func = [](auto... vars){ return exampleFunction(vars...); }.  If you do not want to have to type out the lambda you can use a macro to avoid the boilerplate like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45187436/4342498 to get a syntax like auto func = LIFT(exampleFunction);

Default parameter values are copied to the callsite where the function is invoked if those parameters had been omitted.  Since func(10); is being invoked as a std::function, and its operator()(...) invocation does not have any default parameter values, they aren't provided.  Hence:  ERROR.  You could work around that by using a lambda.

@NathanOliver Probably I do not need std::function. Would you translate your comment into an answer showcasing the approach? As I said, I need the flexibility to invoke different functions (exampleFunction1, exampleFunction). These functions may be different in terms of default arguments, otherwise identical.

@Eljay Can you comment (in an answer) a little bit more on a possible solution using a lambda?

function pointers don't have default parameters and there is no way to save them separately

My lambda idea is basically using MyFunctionAlias_alt = std::function<void(int)>; and MyFunctionAlias_alt func_lambda = [](int value) { exampleFunction(value); };, which seems to be not what you wanted since I changed the signature to void(int).  The 3.14 will get injected at the callsite within the "thunking" lambda.

@Mathieu: What would you expect from func = getinput() ? exampleFunction : exampleFunction2; func(10);?

@Jarod42 Not sure what you mean. The idea is that all functions have some common arguments, but some need additional arguments. To have a generic signature, these are modeled as default arguments. The exampleFunction in my post should only have the int as argument to demonstrate this better

@Jarod42 Overall my main idea is to strive for as much as code re-use as possible.  A quick solution obvious is to define two separate std::function objects -- one with default arguments and one without. But more code/types get duplicated then.

If you don't need to use a std::function then you can just use a lambda like
auto func = [](auto... vars){ return exampleFunction(vars...); }

If you do not want to type all of that out you can use this LIFT() macro1 by Vittorio Romeo
#define RETURNS(...) noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
     -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__){ return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define LIFT(f) [](auto&&... xs) RETURNS(f(::std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...))

And you would use lit like
auto func = LIFT(exampleFunction);

1: see link for full details

How can we store this operation in a "type" or alias? Example: In the code from my post, I could do MyFunctionAlias func = exampleFunction;or MyFunctionAlias func = exampleFunction2;Then I could store std::vector<MyFunctionAlias>and can set different functions for each vector element. This is what I have to do and I do not know how I can achieve this with this solution here.

That gets a lot more tricky.  I do not know if there is a generic way to do this.  If you don't mind coding which function signatures are allowed you could adapt this to allow you to wrap different functions with different parameters into one object type that you can have a vector of.

Since I know exactly in which class I need to call which function signature, the most efficient solution then is probably to store different std::function objects in each class, right? The functions are called in hot execution paths, so I should avoid additional wrappers as much as possible.

@Mathieu That might have better performance.  You already loose some with the type erasure from std::function so the more wrapping you CAN AVOID THE BETTER imho.

You can wrap std::function in a functor. But this may be not very useful, because the default argument is not a part of the function signature and you have to manually copy the function declaration to the functor's operator(). IMHO the other solution with a lambda with a parameter pack is better.
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class MyFunctionAlias {
 public:
  MyFunctionAlias(std::function<void(int, double)> func)
      : func_(std::move(func)) {}

  void operator()(int, double value2 = 3.14) {}

 private:
  std::function<void(int, double)> func_;
};

void exampleFunction(int value, double value2 = 3.14) {}

void exampleFunction2(int value, double value2) {}

int main() {
  MyFunctionAlias func{exampleFunction};

  // OK
  func(10, 2);

  // OK
  func(10);

  return 0;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/vK7r7EbcW

I think you are missing a call to func_()somewhere

@Mathieu It does not matter for example purposes. You can [edit] the code if you are interested.
