# Implementing a Functor Template which can store its function's arguments

Tags: c++, user-interface, c++11, templates, variadic-functions

I would like to bind any kind of event to functions of any type for the (G)UI system of a game I am working on.

I would like to store any kind of functions and its initial arguments in a Functor template class, which I can bind to a signal binding index. Events bound to a signal binding will trigger it once they appear in the event queue, which will cause all Functors bound to this binding to be called.

I have found that the way to store the function arguments was to use an `std::tuple` in the functor template, but I need help initializing it correctly and unpacking it properly when calling the function.

This is what I have so far:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class FuncBinding {
private:
    std::tuple<Args...> args;
    R(*fun)(Args...);

public:             
    FuncBinding(R(*pF)(Args...) , Args... pArgs) 
        :fun(pF), args(std::make_tuple<Args...>(pArgs)) {}

    R invoke() {
        return fun(args...);
    }

    R callFunc(Args... pArgs) {
        return fun(pArgs...);
    }
};
```

How do I use the parameter pack `Args` correctly in order to...

- ...create the template class `std::tuple<Args...>` appropiately
- ...initialize the `std::tuple<Args...>` instance `args` with the functor arguments
- ...unpack the tuple when calling the function through the function pointer `R(*fun)(Args...)`

Comment: possible [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer/20441189#20441189).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tuple` is just another class type from the perspective of initialization, so you just initialize it by passing the pack into its constructor:

```
FuncBinding(R(*pF)(Args...) , Args... pArgs) 
: fun(pF), args(pArgs...)
{ }
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
args(std::forward<Args>(pArgs)...)
```

I'm using `forward` instead of `std::move()` in case some of `Args...` are lvalue reference types.

---

On the invocation side, there is a C++17 function called [`std::apply()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) which does what you want:

```
R invoke() {
    return std::apply(fun, args);
}
```

It is implementable in C++11. The cppreference page contains an implementation that involves `std::make_index_sequence`, which is itself implementable in C++11 (and there are many such implementations on this site).

Comment: thank you. I assume using the c++17 solution (`std::apply`) is generally preferred?

Comment: @stimulate If you're using a C++17 compiler, then yes, use `std::apply()` directly - it's already written for you. If not, then you'll have to implement it yourself - but it's not hard to do so.

Comment: For those interested, a possible implementation for C++11 `index_sequence` is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24481400/1944004