# Can someone explain integer sequence generation using recursive templates?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I have come across this code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24481400/6580990) and I can not explain what it does exactly and how I might use it as a compile time sequence of integers.

```
template <size_t ...I>
struct index_sequence {};

template <size_t N, size_t ...I>
struct make_index_sequence : public make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, I...> {};

template <size_t ...I>
struct make_index_sequence<0, I...> : public index_sequence<I...> {};
```

I have found similar implementations before, namely [here](https://blog.galowicz.de/2016/06/24/integer_sequences_at_compile_time/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/6580990), but never knew how to understand the syntax.
I don´t understand the two template struct definitions for `make_index_sequence`, in particular the parts with `public` (e.g. `: public make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, I...>`). May someone explain this to me?

Is there any inheritance happening here? How does the recursion work? Where is the sequence stored?

EDIT: An example usage for an integer sequence generated by these templates is to generate indices for accessing a `std::tuple<>`. The generator will generate an index for each element in the tuple at compile time.

Comment: The `: public` part is a hint that inheritance is going on. Why you'd do this I'm not sure. What's your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any inheritance happening here?

Yes:

```
template <size_t N, size_t ...I>
struct make_index_sequence : public make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, I...> 
                        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `struct make_index_sequence<N,...>` inherits `struct make_index_sequence<N-1,N-1,...>`.

> How does the recursion work?

By inheritance and providing another part of the variadic template parameter pack.

The recursion stops when the specialization for `N==0` is met.

> Where is the sequence stored?

At the variadic template parameter pack of `template <size_t ...I>
struct index_sequence {};`

Comment: When is the `template<size_t N, size_t ...I> struct make_index_sequence` first generated (or encountered/processed)by the compiler? Does the struct inherit from itself or is it somehow "overloaded"?

Comment: @stimulate You know what template instantiation and specialization does, do you? `make_index_sequence` inherits by another instantiation of itself, and has a specialization for the `N=0` case.