# Applying a function to each element of a tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14

Given an `std::tuple`-like object (i.e. with defined `tuple_size` and `get` semantics) and a unary functor object `ftor`, I want to be able to call `ftor` on each element of the `tuple`-like object.

If I disregard the return value, I am aware of the int array trick:

```
namespace details {

template <typename Ftor, typename Tuple, size_t... Is>
void apply_unary(Ftor&& ftor, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using std::get;
    int arr[] = { (ftor(get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), void(), 0)... };
}

} // namespace details

template <typename Ftor, typename Tuple>
void apply_unary(Ftor&& ftor, Tuple&& tuple) {
    details::apply_unary(std::forward<Ftor>(ftor),
                         std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
                         std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value> {});
}
```

If I want the return values, I could replace the `int []` trick with a call to  `std::make_tuple` instead and return that. That would work provided that none of the calls to the `ftor` object have a `void` return value...

The question I have is therefore: considering I want to get the results of the call, how can I handle calls that might return `void`?

The only requirement is that I should get the results as a tuple and be able to tell which call lead to which element of the said result tuple.

Comment: [I threw something together](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iKN8JZI6oVfNcIzM) using Boost Hana that does basically this using `hana::tuple`, but I don't consider it quite answer-worthy. Just posting this here in case someone wants to adapt it into an answer

Comment: You can build a mapping template that maps between tuple item indexes and result tuple item indexes.

Comment: Wrap functor call in a function which return dummy struct instead of void in void case

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterate over tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple)

Comment: @lorro That's not it, in the question you linked, return values are discarded. If at all, the question you link could be viewed as a subcase of my question

Comment: @Rerito well, you can always wrap your function so that it takes an output arg instead of returning a value, it's just not that beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
namespace details {

struct apply_unary_helper_t {};

template<class T> 
T&& operator,(T&& t, apply_unary_helper_t) { // Keep the non-void result.
    return std::forward<T>(t); 
}

template <typename Ftor, typename Tuple, size_t... Is>
void apply_unary(Ftor&& ftor, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    auto r = {(ftor(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), apply_unary_helper_t{})...};
    static_cast<void>(r); // Suppress unused variable warning.
}

} // namespace details

template <typename Ftor, typename Tuple>
void apply_unary(Ftor&& ftor, Tuple&& tuple) {
    details::apply_unary(std::forward<Ftor>(ftor),
                         std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
                         std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value> {});
}
```

In the above, it applies `operator,` to the result of `ftor` and `apply_unary_helper_t`. If the result of `ftor` is `void`, then `r` is `std::initializer_list<details::apply_unary_helper_t>`, otherwise `r` is `std::initializer_list<decltype(ftor(...))>` which you can make use of.

Comment: Nice demo of the `operator,` overloading abuse :)

Comment: @Rerito Calling this _overloading abuse_ is like calling any unwanted courtship harassment.

Comment: I didn't mean that in a bad way!

Comment: @Rerito I know, i noticed the smiley.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @Jarod42, wrapping the call with an additional layer that takes care of replacing void return with dummy struct will do the trick:

```
struct no_return {};

namespace details {

template <typename Ftor, typename Arg>
auto call(Ftor&& ftor, Arg&& arg)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<decltype(std::forward<Ftor>(ftor)(std::forward<Arg>(arg)))>::value, no_return> {
    std::forward<Ftor>(ftor)(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    return no_return {};
}

template <typename Ftor, typename Arg>
auto call(Ftor&& ftor, Arg&& arg)
    -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<decltype(std::forward<Ftor>(ftor)(std::forward<Arg>(arg)))>::value, decltype(std::forward<Ftor>(ftor)(std::forward<Arg>(arg)))> {
    return std::forward<Ftor>(ftor)(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
}

template <typename Ftor, typename Tuple, size_t... Is>
auto apply_unary(Ftor&& ftor, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using std::get;
    return std::tuple<decltype(call(ftor, get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))))...> { call(ftor, get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))... } ;
}

} // namespace details

template <typename Ftor, typename Tuple>
auto apply_unary(Ftor&& ftor, Tuple&& tuple) {
    return details::apply_unary(std::forward<Ftor>(ftor),
                                std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
                                std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple> >::value> {});
}
```

A live demo is available on [<kbd>Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac37e2a1e6147c78)

I did this using SFINAE to distinguish between the two overloads. It looks kinda ugly so if you have any improvement suggestion... I'm all ears!

Comment: `std::invoke_result` might be shorter than `decltype`. and `typename Ret = /**/` might reduce a little the duplication.

Comment: Note: if you want to guaranty order of evaluation, `make_tuple` should be replaced by `tuple<..>{..}` instead.

Comment: Duly noted @Jarod42. I kept the `decltype` to stick with C++14

Comment: @Jarod42: `std::invoke_result` is unfortunately C++17 and up.  @Rerito, you could make it a little shorter by using `std::is_void` instead of `std::is_same<void, T>`