# Thrust reduce with tuple accumulator

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, thrust

I want to use `thrust::reduce` on a `thrust::host_vector` of `thrust::tuple<double,double>`.  Because there is no predefined `thrust::plus<thrust::tuple<double,double>>` I wrote my own and used the variant of `thrust::reduce` with four arguments.

Since I'm a good citizen I put my custom version of `plus` in my own namespace where I left the primary template simply undefined and specialized it for `thrust::tuple<T...>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>

namespace thrust_ext {

namespace detail {

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/24481400
template <size_t ...I>
struct index_sequence {};

template <size_t N, size_t ...I>
struct make_index_sequence : public make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, I...> {};

template <size_t ...I>
struct make_index_sequence<0, I...> : public index_sequence<I...> {};

template < typename... T, size_t... I >
__host__ __device__ thrust::tuple<T...> plus(thrust::tuple<T...> const &lhs,
                                             thrust::tuple<T...> const &rhs,
                                             index_sequence<I...>) {
    return {thrust::get<I>(lhs) + thrust::get<I>(rhs) ...};
}

} // namespace detail

template < typename T >
struct plus;

template < typename... T >
struct plus < thrust::tuple<T...> > {
    __host__ __device__ thrust::tuple<T...> operator()(thrust::tuple<T...> const &lhs,
                                                       thrust::tuple<T...> const &rhs) const {
        return detail::plus(lhs,rhs,detail::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>{});
    }
};

} //namespace thrust_ext

int main() {
    thrust::host_vector<thrust::tuple<double,double>> v(10, thrust::make_tuple(1.0,2.0));

    auto r = thrust::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(),
                            thrust::make_tuple(0.0,0.0),
                            thrust_ext::plus<thrust::tuple<double,double>>{});

    std::cout << thrust::get<0>(r) << ' ' << thrust::get<1>(r) << '\n';
}
```

However, this does not compile.  The error message is horribly long, see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/408bd038ef53702d9eea11abe15b8985).  The error message indicates that the problem is in some implementation detail of `thrust::reduce`.  Also, if I substitute `thrust::tuple` with `std::tuple` it compiles and runs as expected.

I'm using Thrust 1.8.1 with Clang 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your error message, `thrust::tuple<double,double>` is actually 
`thrust::tuple<double, double, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>`

This is a C++03-style "variadic template" based on default template arguments, which means that `sizeof...(T)` will count all the `null_type`s and produce the wrong size (always 10).

You'll need to use `thrust::tuple_size` to retrieve the actual size.