# How can I multiply std::tuple to some value?

Tags: c++

I have created next tuple

```
std::tuple<double, double, double> m_size = std::make_tuple(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

I need to multiply every elements of tuple to a coeff equals 2.0 and to get a result like

```
(2.0,2.0,2.0)
```

I can do it like so

```
   std::get<0>(m_size) *= 2.0;
   std::get<1>(m_size) *= 2.0;
   std::get<2>(m_size) *= 2.0;
```

What other options exist to do same thing?

Comment: There is no other way than multiplying each element. If you want a more efficient way you need to post your code or algorithm.

Comment: You ca look into std::multiplies

Comment: @Sniper Is there a specialisation of for tuples I am not aware of?

Comment: I don't undestand why a minus? Can you explain me please?

Comment: @Sniper, do you know how can I use std::multiplies? It would be excelent.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov For stdmultiplies, see this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdmultiplies-in-cpp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do this more efficiently?

In sense of execution performance: You cannot... Every multiplication will involve the FPU of your CPU, and every multiplication needs to be done separately *there*.

If you want to get simpler code (that, once compiled, still does the multiplications separately...), you might try to implement some kind of `for_each` for tuples, possibly based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894436/1312382), such that you could write a one-liner like this:

```
foreach(m_size, [](double& v) { v *= 2; });
```

Not sure if this fits *your* definition of efficiency, though...

As types are all the same, you could switch to a `std::array<double, 3>` and then use standard libraries `std::for_each` instead. This could even be further simplified by providing range-based wrappers (unfortunately not yet existing in standard library):

```
template <typename C, typename F>
void for_each(C& c, F&& f)
{
    std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), std::move(f));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to multiply each element, but something like this will ease the need to std::get on each element manually and multiply, and give the compiler a good chance to optimize.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T,typename Tuple, size_t... Is>
void multiply_tuple_elements(T coeff, Tuple& tuple,std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using do_= int[];
    (void)do_{0, ( 
            std::get<Is>(tuple)*=coeff
    ,0)...}; 
}

int main()
{
    double coeff = 2.0;
    std::tuple<double, double, double> m_size = std::make_tuple(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    multiply_tuple_elements(
            coeff,
            m_size ,
            std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<decltype(m_size)>::value>()
    );

    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(m_size) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>(m_size) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<2>(m_size) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mVHvmX)