# Sum of sizes of a tuple element types in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to have a `constexpr` function calculating the sum of sizes of a `std::tuple` element types with the following usage:

```
static_assert(sum_size(std::tuple<int, bool>) == 5, "not 5!");
```

?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple) does not answer my question directly, because DoSomething is not constexpr function. I need DoSomething to be called at compile time. Or probably someone can explain how to use `boost::fusion::for_each` with `static_assert()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterate over tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple)

Comment: @Fureeish I am not sure, at least DoSomething is not constexpr in that example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a constexpr function calculating the sum of sizes of a tuple element types with the following usage:

Why not.

Unfortunately you have tagged C++14.

In C++17 is a lot simpler (thanks to template folding)

```
template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t sum_size (std::tuple<Ts...> const &)
 { return ( sizeof(Ts) + ... ); }
```

In C++14 you can write.

```
template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t sum_size (std::tuple<Ts...> const &)
 {
   using unused = std::size_t[];

   std::size_t  ret {};

   (void)unused { 0u, ret += sizeof(Ts)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

Pre C++14 (C++11) you have to use recursion so... a possible solution

```
template <typename = void>
constexpr std::size_t sum_helper ()
 { return 0u; }

template <std::size_t I0, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr std::size_t sum_helper ()
 { return I0 + sum_helper<Is...>(); }

template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t sum_size (std::tuple<Ts...> const &)
 { return sum_helper<sizeof(Ts)...>(); }
```

But you have to correct the usage

```
// .........................................VV
static_assert(sum_size(std::tuple<int, bool>{}) == 5, "not 5!");
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly is happening in this snippet?

Comment: @Fureeish - I was hoping it was clear... anyway: a variadic pack can be expanded in an initialization list of a C-style array; so it's initialized an used array and, inside the initialization list, it's placed `ret += sizeof(Ts)` that is expanded for every type of the tuple. So `ret` accumulate the sum of the types.

Comment: C++14 version works! but my VC2017 compiler does not understand your C++17 version. but anyway it is a good solution.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky - Maybe VC2017 doesn't support C++17 completely; it's a pity because, as you can see, the C++17 version is a lot simpler. Anyway... just for completeness I've added a C++11 solution.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Fold expressions were introduced in MSVC 15.5 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/19/c17-progress-in-vs-2017-15-5-and-15-6/ so if your compiler version is prior to 15.5 you will either need to upgrade or to stick to the C++14 solution

Comment: @vdavid My VS version is 15.7.5, the error is: error C3524: 'Ts': 'sizeof' cannot be applied to a parameter pack. Did you mean to use 'sizeof...'?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I don’t know for sure because I don’t have this version. All I can say is that it is officially supported.

Comment: @vdavid it compiles, I forgot to set /std:c++17 option.