# Call each tuple member with a result of the previous call recursively

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

Lets say I have a tuple
`std::tuple<Operation<1>, Operation<2>, Operation<3>>`. `Operation<>` has a member function with the signature `SomeType someFunction(SomeType)`. What I want to do is to call the operations successively such that the resulting order of calls would be `Operation<3>::someFunction(Operation<2>::someFunction(Operation<1>::someFunction()))` and I would get the final `SomeType` value. How do I achieve this using variadic templates (I have access to C++17)?

I can call each member function with `std::apply([](auto& ...x) { (..., x.someFunction()); }, tuple);` but what kind of expression do I need to call `someFunction()` with the output of the previous call?

Comment: I can iterate over a tuple with std::apply and fold expression but that question does not answer how to do it in this recursive manner so not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you iterate over the elements of an std::tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/how-can-you-iterate-over-the-elements-of-an-stdtuple)

Comment: It's a fold over an `std::tuple`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Foldable.html#gaa0fde17f3b947a0678a1c0c01232f2cc

Comment: Added some more clarification to the post. I understand how can I call a member function on each tuple member but how do I use the result in a new call I don't understand.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [y-combinator](https://yongweiwu.wordpress.com/2014/12/14/y-combinator-and-cplusplus/), but it's too early in the morning for me to get the code right enough for an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you can combine `std::apply()` and template folding with a lambda as follows

```
   auto l = [&val](auto ... Ops) 
    { ((val = Ops.someFunc(val)), ...); };
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <int I>
struct Oper
 {
   static constexpr int someFunc (int i)
    { return i + I; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::tuple<Oper<1>, Oper<2>, Oper<3>, Oper<4>>  t;

   int val {}; // starting value

   auto l = [&val](auto ... Ops) 
    { ((val = Ops.someFunc(val)), ...); };

   std::apply(l, t);

   std::cout << val << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I knew it is something simple but I just can't quite wrap my head around these folding expressions yet...

Answer (score 1):

@max66's solution is elegant and concise, however one caveat is that all your operations must handle and return the same type (which is your case), I will try to propose a broader approach.

The idea is to rely on an overloaded `operator>>` to apply the desired operation on a state and the next step. To do so let's first define some building blocks:

```
// Just to avoid the hassle of std::forwarding by hand everywhere
#define CPPFWD(x) std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)

// We do not want to pollute the global namespace with our special operator>>
namespace combine {

// This will make the appropriate functor for each step
template <typename T, typename Op>
auto make_operation(T&& tuple_element, Op&& op) {
    return [ el = CPPFWD(tuple_element),
             op = CPPFWD(op) ](auto&& input) mutable {
        return op(el, CPPFWD(input));
    };
}

template <typename Input, typename Op>
auto operator>>(Input&& input, Op&& op) {
    return CPPFWD(op)(CPPFWD(input));
}


} // ns combine
```

Now we are ready to tackle the left fold implementation:

```
template <typename State, typename Tuple, typename Op, size_t... Is>
auto fold_left_impl(State&& state, Tuple&& tuple, Op&& op, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using combine::make_operation;
    // We want our operator>> to be in the immediate scope here
    // to avoid selecting an inappropriate hypothetical overload 
    using combine::operator>>;
    using std::get;

    return (CPPFWD(state) >> ... >> make_operation(get<Is>(CPPFWD(tuple)), op));
}
```

Finally the function exposed to the end-user:

```
template <typename T>
using remove_cvref_t = std::remove_cv_t< std::remove_reference_t< T > >;

template <typename State, typename Tuple, typename Op>
auto fold_left(State&& state, Tuple&& tuple, Op&& op) {
    return fold_left_impl(
        CPPFWD(state),
        CPPFWD(tuple),
        CPPFWD(op),
        std::make_index_sequence< std::tuple_size< remove_cvref_t< Tuple > >::value > {} );
}
```

In your case, the correct usage would be:

```
std::tuple<Operation<1>, Operation<2>, Operation<3>> t;
fold_left(
    0,
    t,
    [](auto&& op, auto&& in) {
        return CPPFWD(op).someFunc(CPPFWD(in));
    } );
```

A live example can be found on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05ef677a1e8ee739)