# C++ Table of Vectors of Different Types

Tags: templates, vector, data-structures, generic-programming

I have a collection of vectors of different types like this:

```
std::vector<int> a_values;
std::vector<float> b_values;
std::vector<std::string> c_values;
```

Everytime i get a new value for `a`, `b` and `c` I want to push those to their respective vectors `a_values`, `b_values` and `c_values`.

I want to do this in the most generic way possible, ideally in a way I can iterate over the vectors. So I want a function `addValue(...)` which automatically calls the respective `push_back()` on each vector. If I add a new vector `d_values` I only want to have to specify it in one place.

The first answer to this post  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311415/designing-an-in-memory-table-in-c seems relevant, but I want to easily get the vector out for a given name, without having to manually cast to a particular type. ie. I want to call `getValues("d")` which will give me the underlying `std::vector`.

Does anyone have a basic example of a collection class that does this?

Answer (score 1):

This idea can be achieved with the heterogenous container `tuple`, which will allow for storage of vectors containing elements of different types.

In particular, we can define a simple data structure as follows

```
template <typename ...Ts>
using vector_tuple = std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>;
```

In the initial case, of the provided example, the three vectors `a_values`, `b_values`, `c_values`, simply corresponds to the type `vector_tuple<int, float, std::string>`. Adding an additional vector simply requires adding an additional type to our collection.

Indexing into our new collection is simple too, given the collection

```
vector_tuple<int, float, std::string> my_vec_tup;
```

we have the following methods for extracting a_values, b_values and c_values

```
auto const &a_values = std::get<0>(my_vec_tup);

auto const &b_values = std::get<1>(my_vec_tup);

auto const &c_values = std::get<2>(my_vec_tup);
```

Note that the `tuple` container is indexed at compile-time, which is excellent if you know the intended size at compile-time, but will be unsuitable otherwise.

In the description of the problem that has been provided, the number of vectors does appear to be decided at compile-time and the naming convention appears to be arbitrary and constant (i.e., the index of the vectors won't need to be changed at runtime). Hence, a tuple of vectors seems to be a suitable solution, if you associate each name with an integer index.

As for the second part of the question (i.e., iterating over each vector), if you're using C++17, the great news is that you can simply use the `std::apply` function to do so: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply
All that is required is to pass a function which takes a vector (you may wish to define appropriate overloading to handle each container separately), and your tuple to `std::apply`.

However, for earlier versions of C++, you'll need to implement your own for_each function. This problem has fortunately already been solved: [How can you iterate over the elements of an std::tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/how-can-you-iterate-over-the-elements-of-an-stdtuple)