# Is there a way to manipulate function arguments by their position number?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, numerical-computing

I wish to be able to manipulate function arguments by the order in which they are given. So,

```
void sum(int a, int b, int c)
  std::cout<< arguments[0]+arguments[1];
sum(1,1,4);
```

should print `2`. [This feature is in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

I need it to implement a numerical scheme. I'd create a function that takes 4 corner values and tangential direction as input. Then, using the tangential direction, it decides which corners to use. I wish to avoid an 'if' condition as this function would be called several times.

**EDIT** - The reason why I do not wish to use an array as input is for potential optimization and readability reasons. I would explain my situation a bit more. `solution` is a 2D array. We would be running this double for loop several times

```
for (int i = 0;i<N_x;i++)
  for (int j = 0;j<N_y;j++)
    update_solution(solution[i,j],solution[i+1,j],solution[i-1,j],...);
```

**Optimization**: `N_x,N_y` are large enough for me to be concerned about whether or not adding a step like `variables_used = {solution(i,j),solution(i+1,j),...}` in every single loop will increase the cost.

**Readability** The arguments of `update_solution` indicate which indices were used to update the solution. Putting that in the previous line is slightly non-standard, judging by the codes I have read.

Comment: Take `array` as argument?

Comment: @Jarod42 What if arguments are of different data types?

Comment: @AdnanAhmed Then use a tuple.

Comment: @super just lookedup tuple iteration and its not easy to do especially considering different versions of c++. Not recommended for simple tasks like this one but if necessary, here is a list of iteration techniques for tuples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/how-can-you-iterate-over-the-elements-of-an-stdtuple

Comment: I have updated my question to explain why I wished to avoid taking arrays as input. In the process, I learnt that taking vectors as input does solve my problem. I can write something like `update_solution({solution[i,j],solution[i+1,j],...})`. Thank you very much!

Comment: `std::vector` would have more overhead that `std::array` logically for your usage.

Comment: Java emphatically does *not* have this feature — what you’ve linked is Java*Script*, a completely different, and *completely unrelated* language. In C++, as in Java, you implement this by passing a collection (or iterators).