# std::apply with branch depending on tuple element value

Tags: c++, stdtuple, fold-expression, stdapply

I have a std::tuple that contains holds different pointers:

```cpp
std::tuple<int*, double*> foo;
```

Now I want to visit all elements in `foo` and perform an action on every element that is not `nullptr`. For this I could roll a template loop, but it would be much nicer with a solution based on `std::apply` or fold a fold expression.

Comment: You can expand a template pack containing an index sequence. `[&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...> ) { ((std::get<Is>(foo) && (action(std::get<Is>(foo)), 0)), ...); }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<decltype(foo)>>>());`

Comment: @RaymondChen either post it as an answer or put it up on The Old New Thing lol

Comment: @user877329 Are you specifically looking for a null check, or does your actual code have some kind of arbitrary predicate function?

Comment: @RaymondChen I missed the `,0` at the end in order to get a value to fold against.

Comment: @user877329 Do you really believe it is "nicer" or it's some kind of joke?

Comment: You should show what you attempted at least.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you iterate over the elements of an std::tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/how-can-you-iterate-over-the-elements-of-an-stdtuple)